# Structure of Graphics (esp. those produced by Plot, ListPlot, etc.)

Tags: plotting, graphics, documentation

I'm looking for a description of the *structure* of `Graphics` objects, *aimed at the advanced* Mathematica *programmer*.

---

The motivation for this question is the following.  I have several `Module`-type functions that, as part of their operation, have to manipulate `Graphics` objects (primarily those generated by plotting commands).  I find that these functions often produce undesired results, and the reason is, invariably, that the function has assumed something about the structure of `Graphics` objects that turns out not to hold in general.  Hence, I want to learn more about the internal structure of the `Graphics` objects generated by `Plot`, `ListPlot`, and friends.

Unfortunately, I cannot distill my overall state of confusion into one or two concrete questions.  I have a ton of questions, but from my ignorant vantage point, I cannot rank these questions in order of importance.  Here's an example out of many I could give: "why do the lists of "primitives" in so many of the `Graphics` objects that I produce with plotting commands begin and end with empty lists?"  For all I know, the answer to this question could just as easily be hugely illuminating, or be utterly banal, or, worse yet, may give rise to further questions.

---

I've read the documentation for `Graphics` and the tutorial [*The Structure of Graphics*](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphics.html) (which, despite the promising-sounding title, did not shed as much light as I'd hoped).  (I've also watched the [Graphics Language Quick Start](http://www.wolfram.com/events/virtual-conference/2012/resources.html), which is generally instructive, but, as its name suggests, far more high-level and beginner-oriented than what I'm looking for.)

Comment: How much do you know about computer 3D graphics in general? Mathematica's approach makes a lot of sense if you have some background in say Direct3D or OpenGL.

Comment: @Hector: the answer is "not much", I'm afraid.  I'm interested in 2D graphics at the moment, though...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A `Graphics` object essentially describes a state-machine. Each object allowed in the primitive list has one of three actions associated with it

1. add to state,
2. display something while accounting for the current state, and
3. save/restore state.

Note, this can be modeled by a stack based system quite easily. According to the documentation, the first two make up the primitives and the last one is done by encapsulating primitives in a `List`.  Truthfully, I think the language used by the documentation is a little rough here, so I would like to make the distinction between [directives](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphicsDirectives.html) which add to the state and primitives which are displayed. In light of the above model, let us examine a simple `Graphics` object

```
Graphics[{Blue, {EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], Disk[]}, Disk[{1,0}]}]
```

[image]

which can be interpreted in terms of the following steps:

1. `{` -> Save state. `state == {}`
2. `Blue` -> `AppendTo[state, Blue]`. `state == {Blue}`
3. `{` -> Save state. `state == {Blue}`
4. `EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}]` -> `AppendTo[state, EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}]]`. `state == {Blue, EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}]}`
5. `Disk[]` -> Display `{Blue, EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}]], Disk[]}`
6. `}` -> Restore state. `state == {Blue}`
7. `Disk[{1,0}]` -> Display `{Blue, Disk[{1,0}]}`

So, then

```
Graphics[{Blue, {Red}, Disk[]}]
```

should result in a blue disk because `Red` has been isolated by being wrapped in a `List`. This also explains why

```
Graphics[{Blue, {}, Disk[]}]
```

also generates a blue disk.  An empty list has no effect, and just hinders readability.

This is a slight over-simplification, as `state` should be thought of as a set of registers, and each directive only effects a specific one. In most cases, only a single function effects a specific register, the color register, though, is effected by many, such as `Hue`, `RGBColor`, etc.  For example,

```
Graphics[{Blue, Red, Disk[]}]
```

produces a red disk because `Red` changed the color register, but

```
Graphics[{Blue, EdgeForm[Red], Disk[]}]
```

produces a blue disk with a red edge because `EdgeForm` does not effect the color register.

There are four additional primitives that need to be discussed: `Directive`, `GraphicsGroup`, `GraphicsComplex`, and `Inset`.  For all purposes that I'm aware of,

```
Directive[{directive..}] == Directive[directive ..] == Sequence[directive ..]
```

as far as `Graphics` is concerned. Its primary use is to group directives together where otherwise you can only supply one, such as in `BaseStyle`.  The last three are container types like `List` in that they save and restore state upon entry and exit.

Comment: Wow. Reading this post was one of the most eye-opening moment I have had on MMA SE. I have been struggling to understand how to use Graphics properly since I've started using Mathematica, and it had never clicked before. Now I think I finally got it: I wish the official documentation was worded this clearly! Thank you very much!

Comment: @MarcoB you're very welcome.

Comment: @rcollyer Really nice explanation. Thanks. While MMA comes with quite thorough help, tutorials provided within the help are often left unfinished and lack insight for deep understanding. Perhaps Wolfram should use MMA SE as a source for tutorials. :)