# Where can I get detailed information on how the Plot command works?

Tags: plotting, graphics, implementation-details

The command

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[{-.025, .025}]] /.Line -> Arrow
```

produces this output.

[image]

What I don't understand is what `Line` has to do with anything. It must be the case that the `Plot` command produces `Line` objects that can be replaced with `Arrow`.  I haven't seen anything in the documentation for `Plot` that suggests this is the case.

Without `/.Line->Arrow` the plot won't have arrowheads at the ends of the graph of the function.

Comment: According to the documentation for [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html), `Plot` normally returns `Graphics[{Line[...],...}]`. See the last two bullet points under "Details and Options."

Comment: I missed that.  Thank you for pointing that out.  Though it does say, "normally returns...".  I hope I don't encounter an abnormal case!  Looking at the documentation for `Line` I think I understand the workings of the `/.Line->Arrow`.

Comment: Related: "[How does Plot work?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29346/280)"

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think that bullet point is missing now, unless I'm overlooking it.

Comment: @ChipHurst Tout ça change...

Comment: @ChipHurst It's the last bullet point in [this documentation for `Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v10.4/ref/Plot.html).

Comment: Thanks. Wonder why it was removed.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I can add to Mr.Wizard's answer that when `InputForm` is wrapped by any head like `List` (`// InputForm // List`) [or by `SequenceForm`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149610/280) the output is much more readable because in this case it is represented in `StandardForm` instead of pure textual representation (and still avoids the [evaluation leaks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144189/280) of `StandardForm`!). `StandardForm` allows semantic selection by double-clicking, wraps the code by window width, highlights the brackets etc. From the other hand it is worth to know that the width of the usual `InputForm` output [can also be controlled](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88543/280).

For inspecting the low-level structure of graphics I find handy my `shortInputForm` function originally published [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6230478/590388). Since that time it undergoes periodic updates for compatibility with newer *Mathematica* versions, so I finally decided to put it [in GitHub repository](https://github.com/AlexeyPopkov/shortInputForm). You can load the function directly as follows:

```
Import["http://raw.github.com/AlexeyPopkov/shortInputForm/master/shortInputForm.m"]
```

The function should work in *Mathematica* starting at least from version 8.

- **01/11/2022 Update**: [`ShortInputForm`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ShortInputForm/) is finally integrated into the Wolfram Language by including it in the Wolfram Function Repository. Users of *Mathematica* 12 or higher can install `ShortInputForm` persistently so that it can be used like a built-in function:

  ```
  ResourceFunction["PersistResourceFunction"]["ShortInputForm"]
  ```

Here is how it formats the output:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}] // shortInputForm
```

[image: screenshot]

`shortInputForm` not just displays a shortened and formatted version of `InputForm` but also allows to select and copy parts of the shortened code into new input cell and use this code as it would be the full code without abbreviations:

[image: screenshot]

---

An advanced description of the *Mathematica* graphical programming language can be found in these threads:

- [Structure of Graphics (esp. those produced by Plot, ListPlot, etc.)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32712/280)
- [How to examine the structure of Graphics objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32716/280)

Some very usefull tricks for obtaining graphical directives applied to every object on the plot can be found in:

- [Is it possible to get current thickness for every Line, Polygon, Circle object in a plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/209038/280)

Comment: I should have been using this function.  Good stuff!  +1

Comment: Regarding the `// InputForm // List` thing, that's a nice trick, but you can also select the graphic and **Convert to InputForm** (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`I`) for an editable InputForm.

Comment: Good alternative. **Convert to InputForm** gives the fixed-width output (what may be desired in some cases) while `// InputForm // List` gives window-width wrapping.

Comment: I wish I had seen this before. Cool. +1

Comment: Might [`ColorQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorQ.html) be helpful in protecting colors?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, it would shorten the code for version 10 but I'm trying to keep the function working at least starting from version 8.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov - I think this function should go into the function repository, it is incredibly useful.

Comment: If you don't object Alexey, I will submit your function to the WFR.  I find I use it almost every day when developing visualization functions

Comment: @JasonB. If you will specify me as the author, I agree.

Comment: @JasonB. Just now `ShortInputForm` is finally [published](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ShortInputForm/) in the WFR.

Answer (score 14):

As far as I know the specific output format of `Plot` (and similar commands) is not documented.  I believe it has changed between versions therefore any post-processing (such as your replacement rule) must be considered potentially version dependent.

As Michael comments above the documentation does state:

> Plot normally returns Graphics[{Line[...],...}].
>
> With a Filling specification given, Plot returns Graphics[{GraphicsComplex[...], ...}].

This tells you the basic format and informs you that [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphicsComplex.html) may be used, therefore you should at least account for that in your post-processing.

Typically the best way to learn the output form of such functions is to view it yourself using [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputForm.html).  You can use [`Short`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Short.html) or [`Shallow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Shallow.html) to limit the size of the expression returned:

```
Shallow[
 Plot[{x, 2 x}, {x, 1, 5}] // InputForm,
 {100, 10}
]
```

You can also replace parts you don't want to view, e.g. `Line` objects:

```
Plot[{x, 2 x}, {x, 1, 5}] /. _Line :> "Line[]" // InputForm
```

Everything in the output expression can be manipulated, including Graphics primitives and options.  See:

- [Is it possible to change the color of plot in Show?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17250/121)

Some aspects of Plot are not obvious or intuitive such as details of the styling chosen.  See:

- [Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/121)

And as linked from my answer there:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605635/detection-and-styling-of-multiple-functions-in-mathematicas-plot/5607141#5607141

---

### `Plot` with arrows

You asked specifically about adding arrowheads to plot lines.  Although post-processing is the only approach I know for this, meaning I am not aware of an option for `Plot` itself, I think it is a good method and I have used it many times.

The syntax for `Line` and `Arrow` is similar, and both work with [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphicsComplex.html), therefore the replacement should be reliable.  However to make the replacement more robust you should focus it only on the part of the `Graphics` object that will contain `Plot`-generated `Line` expressions, since for example a [`Prolog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Prolog.html) or [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Epilog.html) might also contain `Line` expressions.  Here with [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapAt.html):

```
MapAt[# /. Line -> Arrow &, Plot[{x, 2 x, 3 x}, {x, 1, 7}], 1]
```

Or if you have version 10, the operator form:

```
arrows = MapAt[# /. Line -> Arrow &, 1];

Plot[{x, 2 x, 3 x}, {x, 1, 7}] // arrows
```

Worth noting is that even though (AFAIK) you cannot generate `Arrow` expression from within `Plot` you can still provide style directives that will take affect after the replacement:

```
Plot[{x, 2 x, 3 x}, {x, 1, 7},
 PlotStyle -> Array[Arrowheads[#/20] &, 3]
] // arrows
```

[image]

Comment: My goal is to have arrow heads at the ends of plots of functions.  Is there a way to do this without resorting to `/.Line->Arrow` and potentially having things break in future versions?  I have custom plot functions that I use make things look the way I want and I use `/.Line->Arrow`.

Comment: @YequalsX Please see the update.