# BarChart rasterized in EMF export

Tags: export, rasterize

My boss wants several Mathematica graphics as vector graphics in EMF format. All my plots are exported neatly, except for a BarChart which gets rasterized for no apparent reason:

```
Export["test.emf", BarChart[{1, 2, 3}]];
```

The resulting test.emf is almost 1 MB and clearly rasterized.

I found an older threat on the [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396898/why-do-barchart-graphics-exported-from-mathematica-have-pixelated-text-is-there), but was wondering whether there is a new solution to the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### UPDATE

It seems that I found a straightforward way to disable rasterization while preserving the original appearance: the key is to add the `ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Directive[GrayLevel[0.356], Opacity[1]]]` option. The offending dot bug (demonstrated below in the "Original answer" section) we steel have to fix separately via post-processing `/. {Opacity[0], __} -> {}`:

```
plot = BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, 
   ChartBaseStyle -> 
    EdgeForm[Directive[GrayLevel[0.356], Opacity[1]]]] /. {Opacity[0], __} -> {}

Export["test.emf", plot]
```

The above produces a 15 kb EMF file without rasterization. I have checked this workaround in *Mathematica* 7.0.1, 8.0.4 and 10.0.1 and it seems to work reliably. Note that the dot bug was introduced in version 8.

### Original answer

Removing the transparency solves the problem:

```
Export["test.emf", 
 BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] /. {{Opacity[0], __} :> (## &[]), Opacity[_] :> Opacity[1]}]
```

The above produces a 15 kb file without rasterization.

The first replacement `{Opacity[0], __} :> (## &[])` is necessary for removing the redundant black dot at the axis origin:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] /. Opacity[_] -> Opacity[1]
```

[image: screenshot]

In this concrete case the original appearance can be reproduced by replacing non-zero `Opacity` with `GrayLevel`:

```
Export["test.emf", 
 BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] /. {{Opacity[0], __} :> (## &[]), 
   Opacity[o_] :> GrayLevel[1 - o]}]
```

More general way for removing transparency provides `Blend`:

```
Opacity[a_, color_] :> Blend[{White, color}, a]
```

Unfortunately the form `Opacity[a, color]` is rarely used and inspection of the low-level structure of graphics is usually necessary for finding a way to reproduce the original appearance. For this task I recommend my [`shortInputForm` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280).

Comment: Thank you! May I ask, what exactly the statement

    {Opacity[0], __} :> (## &[])

is doing, since it seems to work without it?

Comment: It removes completely transparent objects from the plot. Without it you get a redundant black dot in the plot.

Comment: I have added a screenshot showing the offending dot.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks to your shortInputForm function and the plain ToBoxes string of the graphics I understand what's going on here.

Comment: Admittedly, it's not the kind of solution you would expect from a software as pricey as Mathematica...

Comment: I updated the answer with a new method.

Answer (score 3):

I am the person who originally hit this problem several years ago. Recently Wolfram got back to us with a fix that works for us. It's a slight variation on Alexey's original answer.

```
Export[stringtouse, 
     DeleteCases[ obj /. {_Opacity, p_Point} :> {PointSize[0], p}, _Opacity, Infinity], opts]
```

I bound this up into a little helper function like this.

```
ExportEMFNicely[pathorfile_String, obj_, opts:OptionsPattern[{Export}]]:=
With[{stringtouse = If[ToLowerCase[StringTake[pathorfile,-4]]===".emf", 
 pathorfile, pathorfile<>".emf"]},
Export[stringtouse, 
 DeleteCases[ obj /. {_Opacity, p_Point} :> {PointSize[0], p}, _Opacity, Infinity], opts] ]
```