# BarLegend rasterized in EMF and EPS export

Tags: export

A while ago you guys gave me a splendid workaround to the [rasterization bug in exported BarCharts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65509/barchart-rasterized-in-emf-export).

Now I noticed that the workaround is not working for BarLegends. My problem is, that

```
legend =  BarLegend["Rainbow"]
Export["E:\\test.emf", legend];
```

produces a clearly rasterized file.

Is there any way to get a vector graphic from this simple plot?

Comment: Obviously, the replacements in the workaround for the bug don't work with BarLegends.

Comment: It might have something to do with Hold[...] preserving a BarChart in its unexecuted form, but not a BarLegend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 10.0.2, BarLegends are finally exported correctly in EPS-files. EMF-export is still broken.
Fortunately, it is now possible to generate neat EMF-files from the EPS-files, for example using CorelDraw.