# What will happen if I set ExclusionsStyle for points in 2D plot?

Tags: plotting, undocumented

For example

```
f[x_] := (x^5 - 4 x^2 + 1)/(x - 1/2);
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 2}, Exclusions -> {f[x] == 0}, ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image]

Has the `ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed` option done anything here?

Comment: From the votes I think it is clear that people appreciate your (re)posting this. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think this story told me that while it's important to be friendly to the new comers, it's equally important to place answers under appropriate questions :D

Answer (score 13):

> **Note**: The `Exclusions` option is updated in *v11.0*, since then an additional vertical line at the singularity `x == 1/2` is shown in the plot when `ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed` is added, so you'll find the output of samples in this answer slightly different nowadays, but this doesn't influence the conclusion.

Outwardly, the graph looks just the same as the one without `ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed`:

```
f[x_] := (x^5 - 4 x^2 + 1)/(x - 1/2);
g1 = Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 2}, Exclusions -> f[x] == 0]
```

[image]

But it's surprising that `ExclusionsStyle` does make a difference actually. Let's check the graphs with [Alexey Popkov's `shortInputForm`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/1871):

```
g1 // shortInputForm
```

[image]

```
g2 = Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 2}, Exclusions -> f[x] == 0, ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed] 
g2 // shortInputForm
```

[image]

We can see that in both cases `Exclusions` breaks the curves at `f[x] == 0`, but when setting `ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed`, 3 very short dashed lines are created!

It'll be more interesting if you extend these lines with the `InfiniteLine` in *v10*:

```
Show[g2, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Medium, Point[{x, 0} /. NSolve[f[x], Reals]]}] /. 
Line[{a_, b_}] :> InfiniteLine[{a, b}]
```

[image]

The dashed lines seem to be tangent lines at those excluded points!

Let's check the slopes of the short lines:

```
Cases[g2, Line[{p1_, p2_}] :> (#2/# & @@ (# - #2) &[p1, p2]), Infinity] // Sort
(* {-449.031, -4.26733, 14.6531} *)
```

They're very close to the derivatives at the exclusive points:

```
f'[x] /. NSolve[f[x] == 0, x, Reals] // Sort
(* {-443.273, -4.26733, 14.6531} *)
```

Further check shows that the end points of the short lines are all on the curve:

```
Cases[g2, Line[{p1_, p2_}] :> (f@# - #2 & @@@ {p1, p2}), Infinity]
(* {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}} *)
```

So the short lines are probably short secant lines near the exclusive points, which can be used as approximate tangent lines.

This is not the end of the analysis, [m-goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg)'s answer shows that the working mechanism of `ExclusionsStyle` is even more subtle than what I've represented in this answer, but since my original intention is just to demonstrate the interesting behavior above, I'd like to stop here at this moment.

Comment: "seem to be" - to verify, check the slope of those lines, and compare with the value of the derivative at those exclusion points.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Some more analyses added. (A little busy yesterday :) )

Comment: Yes, I was expecting them to be secants actually, but it's nice how close the slopes are.

Answer (score 7):

I think that I stated this before in a previous post: [`ExclusionsStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExclusionsStyle.html) is a rather strange option. It works differently than other style options and the documentation on it must be read carefully.

The relevant part of the documentation for this question is that concerning the style specification for the *exclusion boundary points*. In the OP's example, where the excluded regions are drawn as dashed lines, only a boundary point style specification will a strong visible effect on the exclusions generated by the plot in question. The dashed lines are too short to show up at the scale of the plot.

```
f[x_] := (x^5 - 4 x^2 + 1)/(x - 1/2);
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 2}, 
  Exclusions -> f[x] == 0, ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed, Red}]
```

[image: plot]

Of course, the exclusion regions can be made visible. Here I do it in a rather gross way, just to make the point.

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 2},
  Exclusions -> f[x] == 0, ExclusionsStyle -> {{Green, Thickness[.1]}, Red}]
```

[image: gross]

Comment: Actually with `ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[{Thickness[.01], Red}]` we obtain similar effect. But +1, interesting.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov. You make a good point. I have edited my answer to make my point clearer and more relevant to the question.

Comment: So the behavior of `ExclusionsStyle` is more subtle than I thought. It's worth mentioning that actually there're 8 red points on the graph.