# How to set default PageWidth for InputForm?

Tags: output-formatting

We can control the page width used by `InputForm` by applying `SetOptions` to `"stdout"`:

```
SetOptions["stdout", PageWidth -> 10];
Range[5] // InputForm
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 
> 4, 5}
> ```

But addition of the line

```
SetOptions["stdout", PageWidth -> 125];
```

to the Kernel "init.m" file has no effect. How is it possible to change the default page width used by `InputForm`?

Comment: Try also adding `Internal\`NewInput=False;` to `init.m`.

Comment: @ilian This does not work: `SetOptions["stdout", PageWidth -> 125];` inside `init.m` does not change the `PageWidth` setting: `Options["stdout", PageWidth]` returns `{PageWidth -> 32}` after launching *Mathematica*.

Comment: Did you add **both** `SetOptions["stdout", PageWidth -> 125];` and `Internal\`NewInput=False;`?

Comment: @ilian, I added both and it did not work, maybe Alexey had better luck.

Comment: Interesting, it did work for me (V10.2 on Linux). Maybe there is something OS-specific. Another idea: `task := SetOptions["stdout", 
  PageWidth -> 125]; RunScheduledTask[task, {1}]`.

Comment: Hi  ilian; I am running Linux Mint 17.1 with 10.2 Running task := SetOptions["stdout", PageWidth -> 125]; RunScheduledTask[task, {1}] changes the PageWidth to 125 but does not do the same for the OP's example of 10.

Comment: @ilian Yes, I tried both `SetOptions["stdout", PageWidth -> 125];` and ``Internal`NewInput=False;`` inside `init.m` (at the same time), I have also tried `task := SetOptions["stdout", PageWidth -> 125]; RunScheduledTask[task, {1}]`  inside `init.m`. Unfortunately both methods do not work and `Options["stdout", PageWidth]` still returns `{PageWidth -> 32}` after launching *Mathematica*. I'm with MMa 10.2 on Win7 x64. With MMa 8.0.4 the situation is the same.

Comment: (I think) I see, what I had suggested applies to the standalone kernel... the frontend will tell the kernel to set `PageWidth` to `WindowWidth` and also change it dynamically on window resize. Perhaps `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, {PrivateEvaluationOptions -> 
{"OutputFormPageWidth" -> 125}}]` will do the trick?

Comment: That works fine for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I think is happening is that the `SetOptions` statement in `init.m` is executed during kernel initialization as expected, however when the notebook window is opened, the front-end sets `PageWidth` to be `WindowWidth`. Furthermore, the kernel value does get changed accordingly whenever the window is resized.

This being the front-end, I would not be surprised if there are other/better ways, but what seemed to work was

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrivateEvaluationOptions -> {"OutputFormPageWidth" -> 125}]
```

<sub>While it was not the culprit in this question, I would still mention that something similar may happen in a console kernel session, where `PageWidth` can be reset by the terminal input library to be the width of the console at startup time. This can be avoided by either turning the terminal library off or using a scheduled task in `init.m`, e.g.</sub>

```
task := SetOptions["stdout", PageWidth -> 125]; 
RunScheduledTask[task, {1}]
```

<sub>so that it runs after the terminal library is loaded.</sub>