# Rasterize: Work around ImageFormattingWidth being broken

Tags: bugs, rendering, rasterize

**Bug introduced in 11.1 or earilier, persisting through 11.3 and fixed in 12.3.1 or earlier** [CASE:4041910]

---

#### Update

The behavior described below only occurs inside the Documentation notebook or for cells with certain styles (e.g. `"Output"`) - I therefore assume the issue is somewhere in the stylesheets, I'll try to investigate a bit more...

#### Original question

[`ImageFormattingWidth`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageFormattingWidth.html) seems to be completely broken:

Using the examples from the documentation,

```
(* Line wrap at 500 printer's points: *)
Rasterize[Expand[(a + b)^20], ImageFormattingWidth -> 500, ImageSize -> 450]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* Do not line wrap: *)
Rasterize[Expand[(a + b)^20], ImageFormattingWidth -> Infinity, ImageSize -> 450]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, the setting has no effect at all. This seems to be caused by the fact that `PageWidth` (which is internally used to handle `ImageFormattingWidth`) does not affect output cells:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], PageWidth -> 300]
a^5 + 5 a^4 b + 10 a^3 b^2 + 10 a^2 b^3 + 5 a b^4 + b^5
```

[image]

How can I still get the intended effect of `ImageFormattingWidth`? The solutions from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88543/how-to-set-default-pagewidth-for-inputform) don't work, and playing around with explicitly wrapping the expression to `Rasterize` in a `Notebook` seems to make it impossible to specify the size of the resulting image:

```
With[
  {exp = Expand[(a + b)^20]},
  Rasterize[
    Notebook[
      {Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@exp]},
      WindowSize -> 250,
      Magnification -> 1
    ],
    RasterSize -> 100
  ]
]
ImageDimensions@%
```

[image]

```
(* {198, 188} *)
```

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until other users have confirmed your observations.

Comment: @J.M.needshelp. I had already confirmed the problem on multiple computers and with multiple people, so I assumed it was appropriate to put the tag there... I'll try to remember to wait for the site community in the future though :)

Comment: @J.M.needshelp. I have received a reply from Wolfram support, and they confirmed that it is not working as documented - I hope it is ok to put the bugs tag back in this case