# Control page width when using ExportPacket[..., "InputText"]

Tags: front-end, export, notebooks, undocumented

Suppose we have a cell like this:

```
boxes = Cell[
   BoxData[RowBox[{"foo", "[", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
      RowBox[{RowBox[{"{", 
          RowBox[{"1", ",", "2", ",", "3", ",", "4", ",", "5", ",", 
            "6", ",", "7", ",", "8", ",", "9", ",", "10", ",", "11", 
            ",", "12", ",", "13", ",", "14", ",", "15", ",", "16", 
            ",", "17", ",", "18", ",", "19", ",", "20", ",", "21", 
            ",", "22", ",", "23", ",", "24", ",", "25"}], "}"}], ",", 
        "\[IndentingNewLine]", "\"asd\""}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
      "]"}]], "Input"];
```

To convert it to interpretable ASCII text, we can use

```
First @ FrontEndExecute @ FrontEnd`ExportPacket[boxes, "InputText"]
```

This produces

```
foo[
 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
  20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25},
 "asd"
 ]
```

Notice that the code was wrapped at a width of about 70 characters. How can I control this wrapping width?

#### "What have you tried?"

`ExportPacket[..., "InputText", PageWidth -> 200]` does not change the wrapping width.

Setting these does not work:

[image]

#### Possibly related:

- [How to set default PageWidth for InputForm?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88543/12)

Comment: That can not be controlled from user land.

Comment: @ihojnicki Is there any other way to convert an input cell's content to relatively nicely formatted plain text, and not wrap it at 70 characters?  It doesn't have to look exactly the same as "InputText", but some spacing around operators would be nice.

Comment: Off of the top of my head?  Not that I can recall.  But when I get a chance, I'll look.

Comment: @ihojnicki For context, it's for converting notebooks to markdown and preserving a relatively readable formatting. Here's the current version: http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/

Answer (score 4):

Here is a trick to make it infinite:

1. mark all existing new lines
2. convert to text
3. remove marks and not marked new lines

```
ToInfWidthInputText[boxes_] := Module[
  {tagged, mark = "ORYGINALMARK", iNL = FromCharacterCode@{62371}}
  ,
  tagged = boxes /. (n : "\n" | iNL) :> mark <> n;
  tagged = First @ FrontEndExecute @  FrontEnd`ExportPacket[tagged, "InputText"];

  StringReplace[
   tagged,
    {
      (mark ~~ "\r"...~~"\n") :> "\n",
      "\\"~~"\r"...~~"\n" -> "", (* in strings *)
      ("\r"...) ~~ "\n" ~~ " " ... -> ""
    }
   ]
  ]
```

```
    ToInfWidthInputText @ NotebookRead @ PreviousCell[]
```

```
 ToInfWidthInputText[boxes_] := Module[
   {tagged, mark = "ORYGINALMARK", iNL = FromCharacterCode@{62371}} 
   , 
    tagged = boxes /. (n : "\n" | iNL) :> mark <> n; 
    tagged = First@FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`ExportPacket[tagged, "InputText"]; 

    StringReplace[
     tagged, 
     {
      (mark ~~ "\r" ... ~~ "\n") :> "\n", 
      "\\" ~~ "\r" ... ~~ "\n" -> "",(*in strings*)
      ("\r" ...) ~~ "\n" ~~ " " ... -> "" 
     } 
    ] 
  ]
```