# Want the colors of the point markers on a multiple-curve, joined ListPlot to match the colors of the curves

Tags: plotting

I am sure that this is rather trivial, but still I cannot find a solution. If there is already a solution here or in *Mathematica*'s help browser, just mention the link.

```
testE = {{0.727694, -10.0477}, {1.02897, -10.045}, {1.32329, \
-10.0419}, {1.63384, -10.0384}, {1.93279, -10.0345}, {2.23407, \
-10.0308}, {2.53534, -10.0267}, {2.8343, -10.0232}};

testD = {{0.723059, -10.0713}, {1.02202, -10.0681}, {1.31866, \
-10.0646}, {1.62457, -10.0602}, {1.92816, -10.057}, {2.22711, \
-10.0522}, {2.53071, -10.0475}, {2.82966, -10.0421}};

testC = {{0.720742, -10.0878 }, {1.02202, -10.0843} ,
   {1.31866, -10.08} , {1.6292, -10.0767 }, {1.92352, -10.0728} ,
   {2.22943, -10.0687} , {2.53071, -10.0654 }, {2.83198, -10.0611}};

testB = {{0.71898, -10.1098 }, {1.01353, -10.1072 }, {1.31736, \
-10.1041 }, {1.61886, -10.1004 },
   {1.92037, -10.0965 }, {2.22188, -10.0925 },
   {2.53034, -10.0878 }, {2.82489, -10.0839}} ;

testA = {{0.709702, -10.1503}, {1.01121, -10.1474},
   {1.30808, -10.1443 }, {1.60959, -10.1406 },
   {1.91805, -10.1369 }, {2.21724, -10.1333 },
   {2.52107, -10.1286}, {2.82489, -10.1239 }};

ListPlot[{testA, testB, testC, testD, testE}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.499, 3}, {-10.16, -10.01}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Orange, Magenta, Green}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"testA", "testB", "testC", "testD", "testE"}, 
 ImageSize -> 600, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]
```

I take

[image]

I wanted the color of the points to match the color of the respective line.
I can do this by superposition but I am sure there is sth quicker.

Comment: I just fount sth: `ListPlot[{testA, testB, testC, testD, testE}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.499, 3}, {-10.16, -10.01}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Orange, Magenta, Green}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"testA", "testB", "testC", "testD", "testE"}, 
 ImageSize -> 600, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]` But still I want to keep the circles.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92118/28

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use use the `PlotMarkers` option together with your list of custom colors.

In passing, I would also suggest that you use `PlotRangePadding` rather than setting a `PlotRange` explicitly.

```
customcolors = {Red, Blue, Orange, Magenta, Green};

ListPlot[{testA, testB, testC, testD, testE},
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> customcolors, 
 PlotStyle -> customcolors,
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1],
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 PlotLegends -> {"testA", "testB", "testC", "testD", "testE"}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Yet another option is to use [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html).  Note the two sets of curly braces around the [`PlotMarkers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html) specification.

```
ListLinePlot[{testA, testB, testC, testD, testE}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.499, 3}, {-10.16, -10.01}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Orange, Magenta, Green}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"testA", "testB", "testC", "testD", "testE"}, 
 ImageSize -> 600, Mesh -> All, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{"\[FilledCircle]", Large}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to generate the plot twice (joined and not) and combine:

```
Show[ListPlot[{testA, testB, testC, testD, testE}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotRange -> {{0.499, 3}, {-10.16, -10.01}}, 
        PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Orange, Magenta, Green}, 
           PlotLegends -> #[[2]], ImageSize -> 600, 
           Joined -> #[[1]]] & /@ {{True, {"testA", "testB", "testC", 
                                 "testD", "testE"}}, {False, {}}}]
```

[image]

Another, probably better, way is to specify both `Joined` and `PlotMarkers->Automatic`

I'd be interested to know if this can be done with `Mesh`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I said I could have worked superposing the graphs (of course not so elegantly like you:-)!). I am also wondering if it can be done by Mesh.