# Customizing a graph (Dashing, PlotMarkers, Labeled)

Tags: plotting, legending

There are actually several questions here but I thought they are closely related so I should not split into several posts. Here we go...

I have the following list

```
data2={{-0.209091, 2.89296}, {0.281818, 2.92958}, {0.8, 2.97535}, {1.28182, 
  3.03028}, {1.8, 3.07606}, {2.28182, 3.11268}, {2.5, 3.1493}, {2.8, 
  3.18592}, {-0.2, 2.74648}, {0.272727, 2.79225}, {0.8, 
  2.83803}, {1.27273, 2.8838}, {1.80909, 2.92958}, {2.28182, 
  2.95704}, {2.50909, 2.99366}, {2.8, 3.03028}, {-0.209091, 
  2.58169}, {0.272727, 2.63662}, {0.790909, 2.69155}, {1.27273, 
  2.74648}, {1.8, 2.77394}, {2.28182, 2.81972}, {2.50909, 
  2.82887}, {2.8, 2.87465}, {-0.2, 2.43521}, {0.281818, 
  2.49014}, {0.8, 2.55423}, {1.27273, 2.59085}, {1.8, 
  2.63662}, {2.28182, 2.66408}, {2.50909, 2.69155}, {2.8, 
  2.71901}, {-0.2, 2.27958}, {0.281818, 2.33451}, {0.790909, 
  2.38944}, {1.27273, 2.43521}, {1.80909, 2.48099}, {2.28182, 
  2.50845}, {2.5, 2.52676}, {2.81818, 2.56338}, {-0.2, 
  2.07817}, {0.272727, 2.14225}, {0.790909, 2.21549}, {1.28182, 
  2.27042}, {1.80909, 2.30704}, {2.27273, 2.36197}, {2.5, 
  2.37113}, {2.8, 2.40775}, {-0.2, 1.83099}, {0.272727, 
  1.93169}, {0.790909, 2.01408}, {1.28182, 2.07817}, {1.80909, 
  2.14225}, {2.29091, 2.16972}, {2.50909, 2.20634}, {2.80909, 
  2.2338}, {-0.2, 1.54718}, {0.281818, 1.65704}, {0.8, 
  1.77606}, {1.29091, 1.84014}, {1.8, 1.92254}, {2.29091, 
  1.97746}, {2.50909, 1.99577}, {2.80909, 2.03239}, {-0.2, 
  1.21761}, {0.281818, 1.32746}, {0.8, 1.47394}, {1.27273, 
  1.57465}, {1.80909, 1.6662}, {2.28182, 1.72113}, {2.50909, 
  1.7669}, {2.80909, 1.80352}, {-0.2, 0.869718}, {0.263636, 
  1.0162}, {0.781818, 1.15352}, {1.29091, 1.26338}, {1.80909, 
  1.39155}, {2.29091, 1.46479}, {2.5, 1.51972}, {2.80909, 
  1.55634}, {-0.2, 0.622535}, {0.272727, 0.714085}, {0.809091, 
  0.851408}, {1.28182, 0.988732}, {1.79091, 1.09859}, {2.28182, 
  1.21761}, {2.5, 1.25423}, {2.81818, 1.3}, {-0.209091, 
  0.411972}, {0.272727, 0.494366}, {0.8, 0.63169}, {1.28182, 
  0.723239}, {1.80909, 0.851408}, {2.3, 0.961268}, {2.5, 
  1.02535}, {2.80909, 1.07113}, {-0.209091, 0.265493}, {0.281818, 
  0.338732}, {0.8, 0.430282}, {1.28182, 0.521831}, {1.8, 
  0.640845}, {2.28182, 0.759859}, {2.50909, 0.796479}, {2.80909, 
  0.860563}, {-0.209091, 0.183099}, {0.281818, 0.219718}, {0.790909, 
  0.292958}, {1.28182, 0.375352}, {1.80909, 0.466901}, {2.28182, 
  0.576761}, {2.49091, 0.61338}, {2.80909, 0.677465}, {-0.209091, 
  0.109859}, {0.272727, 0.146479}, {0.8, 0.201408}, {1.28182, 
  0.256338}, {1.80909, 0.338732}, {2.28182, 0.430282}, {2.50909, 
  0.466901}, {2.8, 0.521831}};
```

Based on the answers I got [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94961/want-the-colors-of-the-point-markers-on-a-multiple-curve-joined-listplot-to-mat) I can plot it as follows

```
ListLinePlot[Partition[data2, 8], Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], Axes -> False, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{\[EmptyCircle], Medium}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(91\), \(\(\\\ \
\)\(o\)\)]\)C", "-88\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(o\)]\)C", 
   "-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(85\), \(\(\\\ \\\ \)\(o\)\)]\)C", 
   "-82\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(o\)]\)C", 
   "-79\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(\(\\\ \)\(o\)\)]\)C", 
   "-76\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(o\)]\)C", 
   "-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(73\), \(\(\\\ \)\(o\)\)]\)C", 
   "-70\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(o\)]\)C", 
   "-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(67\), \(\(\\\ \)\(o\)\)]\)C", 
   "-64\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(o\)]\)C", 
   "-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(61\), \(\(\\\ \)\(o\)\)]\)C", 
   "-58\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(o\)]\)C", 
   "-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(55\), \(\(\\\ \)\(o\)\)]\)C", 
   "-52\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(o\)]\)C", 
   "-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(49\), \(\(\\\ \)\(o\)\)]\)C"}, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

and obtain

[image]

**First Question**
Is it possible the circles to be on the top of the lines and not behind them as it this graph?

**Second Question**
I want the several lines to be distinguishable even in a blank and white printing. I am thinking about applying `Dashing` but I do not know which structure to use in order to do this automatically (as the Default `PlotStyle` does with the colors). The only thing I thought is something like

```
lst = Table[{Black, 
    Dashing[{RandomReal[]/10, Abs[RandomReal[]/10 - 0.1]}]}, {r, 15}];

ListLinePlot[Partition[data2, 8], Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], Axes -> False, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{\[EmptyCircle], Medium}}, PlotStyle -> lst, 
 PlotLegends -> {"-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(91\), \(\(\\\ \
\)\(o\)\)]\)C", "-88\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(o\)]\)C", 
   "-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(85\), \(\(\\\ \\\ \)\(o\)\)]\)C", 
   "-82\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(o\)]\)C", 
   "-79\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(\(\\\ \)\(o\)\)]\)C", 
   "-76\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(o\)]\)C", 
   "-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(73\), \(\(\\\ \)\(o\)\)]\)C", 
   "-70\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(o\)]\)C", 
   "-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(67\), \(\(\\\ \)\(o\)\)]\)C", 
   "-64\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(o\)]\)C", 
   "-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(61\), \(\(\\\ \)\(o\)\)]\)C", 
   "-58\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(o\)]\)C", 
   "-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(55\), \(\(\\\ \)\(o\)\)]\)C", 
   "-52\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\\\ \), \(o\)]\)C", 
   "-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(49\), \(\(\\\ \)\(o\)\)]\)C"}, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

but the output is a mesh.[image]

**Third Question**
Is it possible to arrange the `PlotMarkers` so that I obtain the appearance of plot markers of the following graph

[image]

found [here](http://www.arl.army.mil/arlreports/2007/ARL-TR-4296.pdf)

**Fourth Question** (and final one:-)!)
How can I insert a `Legend` that is mainly text and bypass the associated line as in the above plot?

**(EDIT)**
I corrected the name (`data2` instead of `data`) and also the title (`Labeled` instead of `Legend`) in accordance with [rcollyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/52/rcollyer)'s reply

> 4. In the language developed for plotting/charting, these are labels, not legends. The semantic distinction is immaterial for most concerns,
>      but the implementation for this is not in, yet. But, when it is, you
>      would wrap each data set in Labeled[dataset, label, position].

Comment: You are right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a lot to your question, but first some preliminaries.

Instead of crafting your own markup for degrees Celsius, I would use the `Quantity` framework as it will handle the markup for you, and in my opinion looks better:

```
Quantity[-{91, 88, 85, 82, 79, 76, 73, 70, 67, 64, 61, 58, 55, 52, 49}, 
 "DegreesCelsius"]
```

which you can use directly as the argument to `PlotLegends`. Also, since your data sets are at different temperatures, I would be very tempted to use a rainbow color scheme, e.g.

```
temps = -{91, 88, 85, 82, 79, 76, 73, 70, 67, 64, 61, 58, 55, 52, 49};
ListLinePlot[Partition[data2, 8], Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], Axes -> False, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{\[EmptyCircle], Medium}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Map[ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-91, -49}}], temps], 
 PlotLegends -> Quantity[temps, "DegreesCelsius"]]
```

[image]

as I find it helps guide the eyes. If the data is somewhat jumbled, though, this might not be enough variation to distinguish between the lines, so adding `Dashing` and/or different `PlotMarkers` will help.

**1.** The markers are on top of the line, at least in v10, as they are in the `Graphics` object after the lines. If you are brave, you can look at the output using

```
InputForm@plot
```

But, that tends to be very noisy, and can be overwhelming. Instead, you can extract those primitives from the plot directly,

```
Cases[plot, prim : _Inset | _Line :> Head@prim, -1]
(* Line, Line, Line, Line, Line, Line, Line, Line, Line, Line, Line, 
Line, Line, Line, Line, Inset, Inset, Inset, Inset, Inset, Inset, 
Inset, Inset, Inset, Inset, Inset, Inset, Inset, Inset, Inset}
*)
```

which as you can see shows that `Line` always occurs before `Inset` which is used for the plot markers.

**2.** I would not use `RandomReal` to determine the spacing here as you found out it gives visually unpleasant results. I would stick to the constructs used within `Dotted` and `Dashed` with maybe one addition.

```
{Dotted, Dashed} 
(* {Dashing[{0, Small}], Dashing[{Small, Small}], 
 Dashing[{0, Small, Small, Small}]} *)
```

From this, you can construct your own dashing spec, e.g.

```
Clear[mDashing, dot, dash, longdash];
SetAttributes[mDashing, HoldFirst];
mDashing[spec : {(dot | dash | longdash) ..}] :=
  Block[{dot = Sequence[0, Small], 
   dash = Sequence[Small, Small], 
   longdash = Sequence[Large, Small]},
   Dashing[spec]
  ]
```

where I added `longdash` as the results were reasonable. With this you can easily reproduce the built-in forms using `{dot}`, `{dash}`, or `{dot, dash}`, but it becomes more useful in specifying other patterns, e.g.

```
Graphics[MapIndexed[{#, Line[{{0, -#2[[1]]}, {1, -#2[[1]]}}]} &, 
  {mDashing[{dot, dot, dash}], mDashing[{dot, dot, dot, dash}],
   mDashing[{dot, longdash}], mDashing[{dash, longdash}],
   mDashing[{dot, dash, dot, longdash}]}],
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

But, to make the data sets distinguishable, I would not rely just on the style of the lines, but, instead, use a combination of `Dashing` specs and `PlotMarkers` as together they give you a reasonable range without having to generate a large number of unique dashing specs.

**3.** Yes, there are a couple of answers on this site that give you a wide range of options with regards to markers. [Alexey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85094/52) in particular has some very well written answers on it. But, you might want to check out `ChartElementData["PlotMarkers"]`.

**4.** In the language developed for plotting/charting, these are labels, not legends. The semantic distinction is immaterial for most concerns, but the implementation for this is not in, yet. But, when it is, you would wrap each data set in `Labeled[dataset, label, position]`.

Comment: Amazing! I learn a lot of things!

Comment: @dimitris I added an additional bit of code to add a rainbow color scheme to the plot. I think this helps guide the eye when dealing with data at different temperatures (or, any other auxiliary data).

Comment: @rcollyer The triangle plot markers in the `ChartElementData["PlotMarkers"]` are implemented incorrectly like it was [in themes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54536/280): for example `RegionCentroid@ChartElementData["EmptyMarkers"][[4, 1, 1, 2, 2]]` returns `{0.5, 0.355667}` what even does not coincide with the center of the graph: `RegionCentroid@ChartElementData["EmptyMarkers"][[4, 1, 1, 1, 3]]` returns `{1/2, 0.45}` (but it would be much better if centroids placed at `{0, 0}` as it is currently implemented in themes). Probably it's worth to fill a bug report?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov sure, send it in.