# How can I get information about PlotMarkers?

Tags: plotting, graphics

```
 ChartElementData["PlotMarkers"]
```

> ```
>  {"CenterMarkers", "ContrastMarkers", "EmptyMarkers", "FilledMarkers", 
>   "HalfFilledMarkers", "SimpleContrastMarkers", "SimpleMarkers"}
> ```

```
?CenterMarkers
Information::notfound: Symbol CenterMarkers not found. >>
```

Where can I find information about all these and examples of application?

Comment: No information exists or the question has already been aswered somewhere?

Comment: Hmm. That appears to be my mistake. They're strings and not symbols. Specifically, they're named data that you can query, e.g. `ChartElementData["CenterMarkers"]` will produce a list containing the markers, etc.

Comment: @rcollyer. The Documentation Center is very thin on the subject of `ChartElementData`; there is not article `ref/ChartElementData` for that function.

Comment: @m_goldberg you are correct, but it is my fault for suggesting it to him without giving a further example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
m = 6;

data = Table[(m - n + 1) x, {n, 1, m}, {x, 0, 1, .1}];

cedPM = ChartElementData["PlotMarkers"]

{"CenterMarkers", "ContrastMarkers", "EmptyMarkers", "FilledMarkers", \
"HalfFilledMarkers", "SimpleContrastMarkers", "SimpleMarkers"}

Column[ListLinePlot[data, PlotMarkers -> ChartElementData[#], 
    PlotLabel -> #, PlotLegends -> Table[(m - n + 1) x, {n, m}]] & /@ 
  cedPM]
```

[image]

Comment: A word of warning about incorrect implementation of the triangle plot markers in `ChartElementData["PlotMarkers"]`: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95291/customizing-a-graph-dashing-plotmarkers-labeled/95298#comment258583_95298