# How to plot multiple graphs with same x-axis values on the same graph?

Tags: plotting

If I have multiple variables y1, y2, y3, y4 for y-axis and  phi values for x-axis, then how do I plot these variables, indicating each variable with different black marker? My code is

```
data=Import["simavg1.xls",{"Data",1}]; 
phi=data[[All,1]]; 
csrp=data[[All,2]]; 
crl=data[[All,3]]; 
cArp=data[[All,4]]; 
Plot[{csrp,crl,cArp},phi]
```

but does not work.

Comment: Have a look at [Plot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html).

Comment: dear look but unable to enter phi values on x-axis. my commands are 
data=Import["simavg1.xls",{"Data",1}];
phi=data[[All,1]];
csrp=data[[All,2]];
crl=data[[All,3]];
cArp=data[[All,4]];
Plot[{csrp,crl,cArp},phi]

Comment: Consider using `ListPlot`.

Comment: have you seen [Customizing a graph (Dashing, PlotMarkers, Labeled)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95291/customizing-a-graph-dashing-plotmarkers-labeled/95298#comment258583_95298)

Comment: Also consider `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"` if you are using a recent version of *Mathematica*, e.g. `ListLinePlot[
 Table[{k, PDF[BinomialDistribution[50, p], k]}, {p, {0.3, 0.5, 0.8}}, {k, 0, 50}], 
 Filling -> Axis, PlotLegends -> {0.3, 0.5, 0.8}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]`

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is take each of your lists of y-values into a list of `{x, y}` pairs.  To do this, you `Transpose` each of them with the `phi` list.  This would work,

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{phi, #}] & /@ {csrp,crl,cArp}]
```

But if all of your lists are initially in the `data` array, then all you should have to do is **define** the lists including the x-values from the getgo,

```
csrp=data[[All,{1,2}]]; 
crl=data[[All,{1,3}]]; 
cArp=data[[All,{1,4}]];
```

and now you can just use

```
ListLinePlot[{csrp,crl,cArp}]
```

Comment: dear how to change the dashed colors and plot legends above the graph in this  command
ListLinePlot[{csrp,crl,cArp},Frame->True,FrameLabel->{Style["\[Phi]",Black,Bold],Style["Average (%) Influence Detection",Black,Bold]},PlotLegends->{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(D\), \(\[Chi]\)]\)","\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(D\), \(l\)]\)","\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(D\), \(\[Chi]\), \(A\)]\)"},PlotStyle->{Dashing,Dotted,Dashed},PlotLabel->"(a) n=50"]

Comment: @Amin try something like `PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashed}, {Blue, Dotted}, {Purple, Dashed}}`

Comment: Thanks and what about plot legends position on the graph instead of Right side?

Comment: Dear How I plot this data with respective axis labels