# How to increase dash length in DotDashed

Tags: plotting, graphics, style, plot-themes

How can I modify the usual curve style DotDashed such that the length of the dashed portion is increased or is controllable? For example in

`Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,6.25},PlotStyle-> DotDashed]`

Answer (score 10):

`Dotted`, `Dashed`, and `DotDashed` all evaluate as they are shorthand for a full `Dashing` specification. For example,

```
In[5]:= DotDashed
(*Out[5]= Dashing[{0, Small, Small, Small}]*)
```

where each element in the `List` represents a segment. They come in pairs: line length followed by space length. So, for `DotDashed` there is a `0` length line (the dot) followed by a `Small` space, and a `Small` line followed by a `Small` space. If you want to manipulate the dash length, just change its element in the `List`:

```
Table[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Dashing[{0, Small, d, Small}]],
 {d, {Tiny, Small, Medium, Large}}
]
```

[image]

Other explorations can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95298/52).

Comment: Any other way to do it without using Table?

Comment: @user149973 `Table` is there only to show you what's available in terms of the variation.