# Amending Graphics Options Without Rerunning the Code

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a 1D graph plotted using a certain set of colors and plotstyle. Is it possible for me to change the color(s) and the plotstyle without having to rerun the code.

Comment: No, not in any reasonably simple way.  You'd have to decompose the `Graphics` object and figure out what to change in it.  Then you have to do the change manually.

Comment: Can you give an example? It can be quite easy for simple ones: `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}] /. {ColorData[97][1] -> 
   Directive[Red, Dashed]}`

Comment: Not sure what a 1D graph is, and not sure which code you don't want to rerun.  If this is a list plot, you should always generate your data separately from the plot.  Do you really have such an expensive plot to generate, given the data?

Answer (score 3):

Some tips to get you started with a real simple example.

```
plot = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can extract the colors via

```
Cases[plot, color_?ColorQ, Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FullForm[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Replace the colors using `Replace`

```
plot /. {RGBColor[0.368417`, 0.506779`, 0.709798`] -> Red, 
         RGBColor[0.880722`, 0.611041`, 0.142051`] -> Black}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to replace more complicated items you will need to dig down into the graphical output of `plot`. Typically there is a great deal of numerical data that swamps the screen if you look at the graphic in text form.

To reduce that and try to locate what you might want to edit try:

```
plot /. Graphics -> graphicHead /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} -> Nothing
```

`Nothing` is relatively new (started in 10.2). `graphicsHead` is a bogus `Head` that prevents the plot from displaying.

The output looks like

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which would be helpful in locating the parts that you might want to edit.

Comment: `Nothing` was introduced in 10.2 according to `WolframLanguageData["Nothing", "VersionIntroduced"]`. You could use `ColorQ` to get all colors. Your version misses `GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]`.

Comment: @Karsten7 Thank you for the `ColorQ` tip, always learning something on StackExchange. Modified the answer and also corrected version where `Nothing` began.

Comment: @JackLaVigne You can consider my [`shortInputForm`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280) function which is very handy for investigation of inner structure of graphics. I have it in my `init.m`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thank you for sharing this with me. It works great!!