# Isolating legend from Show combination of plots

Tags: plotting, legending

Best explained by example. The code,

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> {"sin(x)"}];
p2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> {"cos(x)"}, PlotStyle -> Red];
p3 = Show[p1, p2]
```

Gives me this nice picture:

[image: both]

Now I want to isolate the plots and legends for export, so I can do,

```
p1[[1]]
p1[[2, 1]]
```

Which gives me:

[image: plot]

[image: legend]

But doing this on the combination `p3`,

```
p3[[1]]
p3[[2, 1]]
```

produces:

[image: plot and one legend]

[image: only one legend]

where only the legend from the first plot was extracted. Given two plots created separately with individual legends, is there a way to isolate the plot and legends?
It seems like I can isolate the plots with `p3[[1]][[1]]`, but haven't managed to combine the legends. I know I can create the legend manually separately, but I'm less keen on doing that.

Is there a way I can inspect the object `p3` more closely to answer this question for myself? Currently it seems like trial and error by adding `[[1]]` indexing everywhere.

Comment: `GraphicsRow[{p3[[1, 2, 1]],  p3[[2, 1]]}]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way I can inspect the object p3 more closely to answer this question for myself?

This is indeed the right question to ask.  You can look at the expression structure using [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html). This is often overwhelming, so we may need to do something to reduce the amount of information that is shown.  One way is [`Short`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Short.html) or [`Shallow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shallow.html).

```
Shallow[InputForm[p3]]
```

[image]

```
Shallow[InputForm[p3], 5]
```

[image]

Originally, all graphics were represented with `Graphics` expression.  `Show` could combine *only* `Graphics` expressions.  Anything else it could handle it converted to `Graphics` first.

Legending works by wrapping with [`Legended`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html).

This is how you construct a legended plot manually:

```
Legended[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
 LineLegend[{Blue}, {"sin x"}]
]
```

This is what is `Plot` produces automatically as well.

The first element in `Legended` will be the return value of `Plot`, a `Graphics` expression. The second element stays unevaluated as `LineLegend[{Blue}, {"sin x"}]`, however, *it displays as a legend*.  Just like `Graphics[...]`, it does not *evaluate* to something, it simply *displays* in a certain way.  The expression structure is not modified.

This is the first bit necessary to understand what is happening.

The second bit is that `Show` is now extended to handle `Legended` expressions.  It does so by combining all the contained `Graphics` normally and placing them into an innermost `Legended`.  However, the legend expressions (such as `LineLegend`) are not combined. Instead they are placed in a nested `Legended` structure which looks like

```
Legended[
  Legended[
    combinedGraphics,
    legend1
  ],
  legend2
]
```

Then it is the formatting of `Legended` that handles displaying this in a proper way.

Comment: @bjorne - On the note of inspecting objects more closely, I'd like to add that `TreeForm` is good for a visual view. i.e. `Shallow@TreeForm@p3` works too.

Comment: Thank you, this is very eye-opening!

Comment: (+1) My [`shortInputForm`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280) function is handy for such purposes.