# Pattern matching problem in version 11.01

Tags: plotting, pattern-matching, function-comparison

Consider this simple example:

```
p1 = ListPlot3D[
   Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}], 
   Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ColorFunction -> Hue];
p2 = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> Hue, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None,
    Axes -> False, Boxed -> False];

p1[[1, 2, 1, 1]]
```

[image]

```
Cases[p1[[1, 2, 1, 1]], GraphicsGroup[{Polygon[x__], ___}] :> x, ∞]
```

[image]

```
p2[[1, 2, 1, 1]]
```

[image]

```
Cases[p2[[1, 2, 1, 1]], GraphicsGroup[{Polygon[x__], ___}] :> x, ∞]
(*{}*)
```

So why does the last pattern match fail?

I'm using version 11.01 on macOS 10.12.

Comment: I'm filing a bug report on this.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I don't think this is a bug, at least not a bug in pattern matching.  Take the subexpression which looks like the list inside of `GraphicsGroup`: `list = p2[[1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1]];`.  It's not a list.  `Head[list]` gives `Annotation`.  `Annotation` formats the same way as its first argument, so this is all very confusing.  The second argument in Annotation is ``"Charting`Private`Tag$4433#1"`` on my machine, which looks a bit weird, but that's a different issue.

Comment: This will work: `Cases[p2[[1, 2, 1, 1]], 
 GraphicsGroup[Annotation[{Polygon[x__], ___}, ___]] :> 
  x, \[Infinity]]`

Comment: @Szabolcs This example definitely changed behavior recently. Maybe you are correct and this is simply due to a change in the structure of the ListPlot3D result, so I need to double check on that. The timing specifics of the onset of the change is what made me suspect a bug in pattern matching. Believe me, I would be delighted to find out I have assessed this one incorrectly.

Answer (score 5):

This particular case is a good illustration of why it would be very useful to have a built-in analog of my [`shortInputForm`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280) function:

```
Import["http://raw.github.com/AlexeyPopkov/shortInputForm/master/shortInputForm.m"]
```

Let us compare `p1` and `p2` using `shortInputForm`:

```
p1[[1, 2, 1, 1]] // shortInputForm
p2[[1, 2, 1, 1]] // shortInputForm
```

[image: screenshot]

From the output we immediately see that in the case of `p2` the first argument of `GraphicsGroup` is wrapped by `Annotation`. That's why the pattern doesn't work for `p2`.

Knowing this we can pre-process the output and remove `Annotation`, then the pattern will work:

```
Cases[p2 /. Annotation -> (#1 &), 
 GraphicsGroup[{Polygon[x__], ___}, ___] :> x, ∞]
```

[image: screenshot]