# Generate code from figure modification obtained through Drawing tools

Tags: graphics, drawing

Sometimes it is useful to use the [Drawing tools](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette.html) palette for adding a label, line or arrow to a graph. Unfortunately when remaking the plot the modifications are not present.

Is there a way to transfer (like copy-paste) the modifications or, even better, to generate the code of the them, like MATLAB allows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method to retreive the manual modifications are more or less complicated depending of the kind of modifications you have done.

I will describe how to do it for the simplest case : the operator simply add one object with Drawing tools.

It is assumed that the OP wants that the retreived graphics should be at the exact same position as the initial ones.

First a animation showing how the operator make a manually modified graphic and affects it to a variable (named `gr01`) :

[image]

We are going to inspect what is `gr01` and what's inside:

```
Head[gr01]
```

> ```
> Graphics
> ```

To see what contains `gr01` we one can do `InputForm[gr01]`.

The result is a long complicated expression which is hard to understand.

It's better to take the first element of `gr01` : `gr01[[1]]` (the other element are options, see documentation of `Graphics`).

`InputForm[gr01[[1]]]` gives :

> ```
> {{{}, {}, {RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], Opacity[1.], 
>  Line[{{1.7453292519943294*^-7, 3.0461741978670854*^-14}, {0.16786653520533412, 0.02817917364184368}, {0.34985290613417436, 0.12239705593052741}, {0.5197793485395309, 0.27017057116817916}, {0.6863725086813754, 0.4711072206735648}, {0.8670856790796513, 0.75183757486502}, {1.0357389209544434, 1.0727551123798749}, {1.218512173085667, 1.4847719159579544}, {1.3979521429533783, 1.9542701939879428}, {1.5707961522619713, 2.4674005519610143}}]}},   {EdgeForm[{GrayLevel[0.], Opacity[1.], AbsoluteThickness[1]}], EdgeForm[None], Arrow[{{0.456803410502701, 1.793764733188572}, {0.8335484908870919, 0.708557516931895}}]}, {}}
> ```

That's rather tedious to read, though I have deliberatly minimized the number of point to 10 in the code above `Plot[ ....,PlotPoints-> 5,MaxRecursion->0]`.

That's the reason why I suggest to use a nice function `shortInputForm[]` created by [Alexey Popkov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov) (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/5467)). Here is how to load directly the function:

```
Import["http://raw.github.com/AlexeyPopkov/shortInputForm/master/shortInputForm.m"]
```

Then `shortInputForm[gr01[[1]]]`gives :

> [image]

Interpretation :

- `Line[{{1.74533*10^-7, 3.04617*10^-14},<<9>>}]`  means : `Line[{{1.74533*10^-7, 3.04617*10^-14} ... "and 9 others couples of values"}]` (here is the effect of the function `shortInputForm`)
- `Arrow[...]`is the arrow that the operator has added.
- Other elements, `EdgeForm`,`GrayLevel`,`Opacity`,`AbsoluteThickness` ... are rendering directives attached to `Line[]` and `Arrow[]`

One can retrieve either :

- `Arrow[...]` alone (`gr01[[1,2,3]]`)
- `Arrow[...]` with the attached directives (`gr01[[1,2]]`).

If one only want to retreive `Arrow[...]` alone, it is simpler to use `Cases[gr01,Arrow[___],{0,-1}]`

(If you want to retrieve the graphic object + the directives, without using the cumbersome indexation, use : `Extract[gr01,Drop[#,-1]& /@ Position[gr01,Arrow[___]]]`)

```
myManualModification00=Cases[gr01,Arrow[___],{0,-1}];
```

> ```
> {Arrow[{{0.456803, 1.79376}, {0.833548, 0.708558}}]}
> ```

Finally :

Suppose one wants to add the modifications to the following graphic :

```
Plot[{x^2,x^3},{x,0,Pi /2},PlotPoints->10,MaxRecursion->0]
```

[image]

Copy-Paste the graphic inside a `Show[_,Graphics[myManualModification00]]`

[image]

One could use also `Epilog->`, but it turns out that the `Arrow` is no more selectable/modifiable in the final graphic.

Answer (score 3):

My teacher just solved the question starting from the suggestion `FullForm[g]` and then developing the method.

First store in `g` the plot to which we manually added the text.

Then use `t = Cases[g, _Inset, All]` and finally `Plot[g, Epilog->t]`

Comment: You surely want `Cases`, not `Case`.

Comment: Great, you made it!

Comment: I think I would use `InputForm` rather than `FullForm`, but it's not usually a huge difference.

Answer (score 2):

The resulting `Graphics` object contains the code. Just store it, e.g. by executing `g = %` just after the editing.

Comment: And once stored how can I extract only the code about the inserted labels? To be able to applying the to other figures?

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean. Have a look at `FullForm[g]`, that tells you how the `Graphics` object is structure and you can copy parts from it. Better try that with a simple `Graphics` object for the start.

Comment: `FullForm[g]` gives a very long expression. I recommend to use the function `shortInputFrom` [obtainable here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/5467)

Comment: I can't find the function ShortInputForm, is a display style for the current line?

Comment: @andre You brought up `shortInputFrom`, you explain it.

Comment: @Nisba Simply evaluate `Remove[shortInputForm];Import["http://raw.github.com/AlexeyPopkov/shortInputForm/master/shortInputForm.m"]` and then you will have the function `shortInputForm`. I will make an answer today (it takes time !)

Answer (score 1):

(A little addition to the excellent [answer by andre](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163596/280))

It seems that the primitives added via the [Drawing tools](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette.html) palette are always placed at the end of the first argument of `Graphics`. With [andre](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5467/andre)'s [example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163596/280) the original `Graphics` object has `List` of length=1 as the first argument, hence they can be obtained as follows:

```
myManualModification00 = Rest[gr01[[1]]]
```

> ```
> {EdgeForm[{GrayLevel[0.], Opacity[1.], AbsoluteThickness[1]}], EdgeForm[None], 
>  Arrow[{{0.456803410502701, 1.793764733188572}, {0.8335484908870919, 0.708557516931895}}]}, {}}
> ```

Then one can proceed as he suggests with `Show[_,Graphics[myManualModification00]]`.

Answer (score 0):

I use 12.0.0. All the above is nonsense for me.

Just use right-clicks on whatever platform you are on the drawing editing you have done. With the open right-click-menu click `Copy Graphic`. Give a variable name and paste the copied graphics into the line.

The rest can be done as explained by the others. There is only some extra effort for the position. But that is most probably better done with a built-in command than by hand with the Drawing Tools.

Stay exact where possible.