# Why _Line works in this Cases as pattern?

Tags: functions, pattern-matching

I got this from examples, and it works, but I can not understand it

first the initial data

```
f1[x_] := 4 x^3 + 0.1 x^2 - 7 x - 1
pss = Plot[f1[x], {x, -1.3, 1.53}]
```

then

```
mx = Max[Last /@ Level[Cases[pss, _Line, Infinity], {-2}]]
```

or

```
mn = Min[Last /@ Level[Cases[pss, _Line, Infinity], {-2}]]
```

both work but I do not understand this _Line  ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This goes back to the basic structure of expressions in WL. *Every* expression has a `Head`, even the built-in operators, like `List`:

```
FullForm[{1,2,3}]
(*List[1,2,3]*)
```

For a pattern,

```
_h
```

this will match expressions with `Head` `h`. So, in

```
Cases[pss, _Line, Infinity]
```

`_Line` matches `Line[...]`. Note: it won't match the bare symbol, e.g.

```
MatchQ[Line, _Line]
(* False *)
```

because

```
Head[Line]
(* Symbol *)
```

Comment: Now I saw, after doing FullForm that the only part of huge basic commands is the one preceded by Line,   before I did not undertand how complex a simple Plot can be.   Thanks for help @rcollyer

Comment: @AnxonPués I don't recommend viewing `Plot` using `FullForm` it's liable to drive you mad. :) `InputForm` is bad enough. A difficulty is that the `FullForm` is how an expression is interpreted, but due to wanting "nice" markup, the details are often hidden. Try `a/b`, for instance. :)

Comment: @AnxonPués You may want to try [`shortInputForm`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/1871).