# What is the use of FullForm in Mathematica?

Tags: functions, core-language

I would like to know where this "FullForm" in Mathematica will be useful. Kindly provide some examples. I just started learning Mathematica. If my question is wrong or not correct. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Whenever a student asks me a question about Mathematica where I don't know the answer, I apply FullForm. Either this helps show what happened, or else it gives me time to think of something else.

Answer (score 27):

Perhaps there are other uses, but I've primarily used `FullForm` to "see" what Mathematica "sees". This can be useful when you are trying to do replacements on something like $\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}}+y^2+1/z$. What Mathematica actually sees is

```
Plus[Times[Power[5, Rational[-1, 2]], x], Power[y, 2], Power[z, -1]]
```

You might want to do a replacement such as:

```
Plus[Times[Power[5, Rational[-1, 2]], x], Power[y, 2], Power[z, -1]]/.Rational[-1, 2] -> 6
(* 15625x + y^2 + 1/z *)
```

Replacements generally match to the `FullForm` and in some cases replacements will fail because Mathematica interprets it differently than you do. For example:

```
x/Sqrt[5] + y^2 + 1/z /. Sqrt[5] -> 6
```

This fails to give the expected result, because there is no `Sqrt` in the function by the time you go to run it.

Another place I've used `FullForm` is for inspecting the code for graphics and plots when they are misbehaving. There's a lot of stuff that happens behind the scenes when generating a plot, and so sometimes it's beneficial to see what the actual result of all that code is. For example, I can see what tick marks were chosen, and I can even replace them with my own tick marks after the fact if I desire. However, I would usually use `InputForm` for this as I find it slightly more readable.

Comment: For inspecting graphics my [`shortInputForm`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280) function is much more handy than `InputForm`.

Comment: And `InputForm` can be achieved by Ctrl+Shift+I. (There exist cases that `InputForm` is missleading of course e.g. `Sqrt[2] // InputForm`.)

Comment: FullForm is tremendously useful for understanding precedence in pattern matching as well. That's where I most rely on it.