# Is it possible to get current thickness for every Line, Polygon, Circle object in a plot?

Tags: graphics, front-end, dynamic, style, undocumented

When exporting *Mathematica* graphics to raster formats with high resolution the common problem is that thickness for such objects as `Line`, `Polygon` (via `EdgeForm[]`) etc. is often specified via `AbsoluteThickness` instead of relative `Thickness`, and hence with high value of `ImageSize` or `ImageResolution` on `Export` these objects change their appearance in an undesired way. This thickness setting usually isn't specified as a styling directive immediately before the object itself, but can be inherited from the upper levels or a stylesheet.

Is there a way to find out `CurrentValue` of thickness for every object on the plot in order to be able to set appropriate relative `Thickness` for the object before exporting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you can use a tooltip with [`CurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentValue)? For example, here's a random graphics object:

```
g = Graphics[{
    Thickness[.1],
    Green,
    {
        Circle[{0,0}],
        Red,
        Line[{{0,0},{1,1}}],
        {
            Blue,
            AbsoluteThickness[1],
            Polygon[{{0,1},{1,0},{1,1}}]
        }
    }
}]
```

[image]

Replace every [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line), [`Polygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon) and [`Circle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Circle) object with a tooltip specifying the thickness and color:

```
g /. l:_Line|_Polygon|_Circle -> Tooltip[
    l,
    <|"Thickness"->Dynamic@CurrentValue["Thickness"], "Color"->Dynamic@CurrentValue["Color"]|>
]
```

After the replacement, each graphics primitive now has a tooltip with an association giving the thickness and color being used.

**Addendum**

If you want the information non-interactively, you can convert the dynamics to literals. Here is a function that does this:

```
showCurrentValues[g_Graphics] := Module[{nb},
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        nb = CreateDocument[
            ExpressionCell[
                ReplaceAll[
                    g,
                    p_Line | p_Circle | p_Polygon :> Tooltip[
                        p,
                        Dynamic @ <|
                            "EdgeThickness" -> CurrentValue[EdgeThickness],
                            "Thickness" -> CurrentValue[Thickness]
                        |>
                    ]
                ],
                "Input"
            ],
            Visible->False
        ];
        FrontEndExecute @ FrontEnd`NotebookDynamicToLiteral @ nb,

        First @ NotebookImport[nb,"Input"->"Expression"]//InputForm,

        NotebookClose[nb]
    ]
]
```

For your example in the comments:

```
showCurrentValues @ Graphics[{
    Thickness[0.01],
    EdgeForm[Thickness[0.02]],
    Polygon[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}]
}]
```

> Graphics[{Thickness[0.01], EdgeForm[Thickness[0.02]], Tooltip[Polygon[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
>      <|"EdgeThickness" -> 0.02, "Thickness" -> 0.01|>]}]

Comment: Thank you, it is definitely a step in the right direction. But I wish to get this information in a programmatic way, non-interactively. Also, for `Polygon` defined as `{Thickness[.1], EdgeForm[Thickness[.2]], Polygon[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}]}` the tooltip shows `Thickness[.1]`, while actually it is `EdgeForm[Thickness[.2]]`. Is it possible to access thickness specified via `EdgeForm` too?

Comment: Thank you very much, the "Addendum" section is exactly what I need.