# Suppress arguments in output for pretty print

Tags: replacement, output-formatting, expression-manipulation, rule

I would like to define a rule that suppress any arguments of a function for visibility.
I tried:

```
rule = f_[x__] -> f
```

While this works well with individual terms (including derivatives of expressions), products of functions don't work, such as

```
f[x] R[r] /. rule
```

which outputs "Times" for some reason?

Comment: It's because `Head[f[x] R[r]]` is `Times`.

Comment: What should be displayed for `f[ g[x] ]`?

Comment: Good question. While this may be seen as unfortunate, the answer to that question would be just "f", since g(x) is an argument.

Comment: I think I have a good answer to this question, so it would be nice to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `Head[f[x] R[r]]` is `Times`. You should rewrite your rule as

```
rule = f_[x__] /; ! MatchQ[f, Times] :> f
```

Now

```
f[x] R[r] /. rule
```

> ```
> f R
> ```

---

> I would like to define a rule that suppress any arguments of a function for visibility.

I think my [`shortInputForm`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280) function can be of interest for you. It doesn't completely suppress arguments but rather shortens long lists of numbers for readability.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can create a wrapper that modifies the box generation code so that it never generates brackets:

```
MakeBoxes[SuppressBracketArguments[expr_], StandardForm] ^:= ReplaceAll[
    MakeBoxes[expr,StandardForm],
    RowBox[{h_, "[",___,"]"}]->h
]
```

A couple examples:

```
f[g[x]] //SuppressBracketArguments
f[x] g[y] //SuppressBracketArguments
```

> f
>
> f g