# PointValuePlot can't generate vector figure when set ColorFunction->"Rainbow"

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, pdf-format

It's amazing that 12.2's new function `PointValuePlot` can't generate vector figure when I set `ColorFunction->"Rainbow"`. Then I save the figure as PDF, I am sure it's not an vector figure. Is this due to my computer problem? How to solve it if I want to use `ColorFunction->"Rainbow"`?

---

Code:

```
PointValuePlot[
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}] -> RandomReal[{0, 100}, 100],
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
    FrameTicks -> None,
    FrameStyle -> Thick
]
```

Very Thanks!

---

### Update

Steps:

1. Use the aforementioned code, you can get a figure, then generate a palette from this figure, you can use `Alt+P+P` as shortcut key.
2. Save this palette as pdf, and observe whether it is an vector figure.

According to my experiment, this problem only occur with `ColorFunction`.

Example Figures:

1. No `ColorFunction`
   [image: Vector Figure]
2. With `ColorFunction`
   [image: Not an Vector Figure]

Comment: Can you give steps to reproduce the problem? Does the same thing happen without the ColorFunction specification? Does it happen with different ColorFunctions?

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/262640/280

Answer (score 2):

### Update

I have rechecked the described behavior of `Export` with versions 12.3.1 and 13.0.0 on Windows 10 x64, and the problem isn't reproduced. It seems they have fixed `Export` in version 12.3.

---

### Original answer

This is due to `VertexColors` used in the output. You can see it's internal structure with my [`shortInputForm`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280) function:

```
pl = PointValuePlot[
   RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}] -> RandomReal[{0, 100}, 100], 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", FrameTicks -> None, 
   FrameStyle -> Thick];

pl // shortInputForm // Short
```

> [image: output]

One can get rid of `VertexColors` by applying `Normal`. Then the plot is exported without rasterization:

```
Export["PointValuePlot.pdf", pl // Normal] // SystemOpen
```

[image: screenshot]

This isn't a bug, but I suggest writing a *suggestion for improvement* about this issue to the official technical support.

Comment: Thanks very much, bro.