# Why does specifying a ColorFunction make figures non-vectorial?

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, color, pdf-format

If I save the figure generated by `ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}]` as a PDF and open it in Affinity Designer (an alternative to Adobe Illustrator), the figure is vectorial and I can modify individual points, axes, etc. However, if I save the figure generated by `ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}},  ColorFunction -> Function[{x}, Blend[{Red, Blue}, x]]]`, I get a rasterized image whose elements cannot be modified. Is there a way to get a vectorized image while specifying a `ColorFunction`?

Comment: Which *Mathematica* version do you use? I don't reproduce this problem with versions 12.3.1 and 13.0.0 on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: working fine here too with MMA12.3.0  on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: The issue is the same as in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/245774/280) question, but applying `Normal` doesn't help here (it drops the coloring information, what I consider as a bug).

Comment: Thank you, I am using Mathematica 12.1.0.0 on Mac OS X 11.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be done easily with lines and polygons (because you'd have to construct gradients but subdividing the objects), but it could be done with points, as in your example. Are you only interested in `ListPlot` of points?

```
vcRules[vc_] := {
   HoldPattern[Point[p_List, VertexColors -> Automatic]] :>
     ({RGBColor @@ vc[[#]], Point[#]} & /@ p),
   HoldPattern[Point[p_List, VertexColors -> c_List]] :> 
     Riffle[c, Point[#] & /@ p]
   };
ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x}, Blend[{Red, Blue}, x]]] /.
 
 GraphicsComplex[p_, g_, o1___, HoldPattern[VertexColors -> vc_], o2___] :>
  GraphicsComplex[p, g /. vcRules[vc], o1, o2]

Export["/tmp/test.pdf", %];
Import[%, "PageGraphics"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or this direct way:

```
ListPlot[
 MapThread[
  Style,
  {#, Function[{x}, Blend[{Red, Blue}, x]] /@ 
      Rescale[#[[All, 1]]]} &@{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}}
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: Maybe I should add that it is the presence of `VertexColors` that triggers the rasterization, which happens when you specify a `ColorFunction` in `*Plot*` functions.

Comment: (+1) Actually, `Normal` should do the conversion. But currently, it simply drops the `VertexColors` what I consider as a bug.