# Plotting an oriented contour

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I'd like to add at least one arrow to a closed contour in the plane to show that e.g. a circumference is counterclockwise oriented. If I use e.g.

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[Exp[I t]], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

how can I insert an option to add arrows along the circumference or other closed contour?

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

pp = ParametricPlot[ReIm[Exp[I t]], {t, 0, 2 π}];

Show[pp,
 Graphics[Arrow /@ 
   Partition[Cases[pp, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1]], 221]],
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Re question in comments, to reverse the arrows change the [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) to

```
Graphics[Arrow /@ 
  Partition[Reverse[Cases[pp, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1]]], 
   221]]
```

Comment: Thanks, very interesting.

Comment: Thank you, very useful. If the orientation would be clockwise, what must be changed?

Comment: @CharlesG - See edit above

Answer (score 5):

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[Exp[I t]], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}] /. 
 Line[data___] :>  {Arrowheads[{{.1, 0.1}, {.1, 0.5}}], Arrow[data]}
```

[image]

There are a lot of explanations about the post-processing `.../.Line[data__] :> ...`  [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55538/5467)

In `Arrowheads[{{.1, .09}, {.1, 0.5}}]` the `.1` specify the size of the arrows, `.09` and `0.5` their location along the Line. See Arrowheads documentation.

Comment: Thank you for this

Comment: Thank you, very useful. If the orientation would be clockwise, what must be changed?

Comment: @CharlesG Negative sizes invert the arrows. Try for exemple : `Arrowheads[{{-.1, 0.1}, {.1, 0.5}}]`

Answer (score 3):

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[Exp[I t]], {t, 0, 2 π}, 
 PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[Table[Large, 4]]] /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[Exp[I t]], {t, 0, 2 π}, 
  PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[Table[-Large, 4]]] /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very useful.

Comment: If the orientation would be clockwise, what must be changed?

Comment: ParametricPlot[ReIm[Exp[-I t]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[Table[Large, 4]], Axes -> False, 
     Frame -> True] /. Line -> Arrow

Comment: @CharlesG, please see the update.