# Why InputForm of iconized output are hard to read in recent versions of Mathematica? How to correct it?

Tags: output-formatting, display, iconize

I never liked WRI tendency to now iconize some results from computation in the notebook. I do not know if this is the correct term for it.

I like to see result always in plain normal code.  Here is an example

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqn = y''[t] + b y'[t] + (c0 + c1 t + c2 t^2 + c3 t^3) y[t] == 0;
sol = y[t] /. First@DSolve[eqn, y[t], t]
```

it gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And one is supposed to click on the icon to get some information. But I want to see the plain text solution.

When applying `InputForm`, the output get chopped and not readable. This is inside notebook with 100% zoom on windows 10.

```
 InputForm[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Can't read it. In version 12.2 it was readable. Below is screen shots showing same output in version 11.3, 12.2, and 12.3.1.

Is there a better option to see the solution, without this icon thing showing up? As `InputForm` is not helping too much here.

If I make the resolution 300%, then output of `InputForm` above becomes readable. But I can't have resolution at 300%.  it seems to do with the `Format` used.

Any workaround?

version 12.3.1 on windows 10.

Here is some comparison

**Version 11.3**

[image]

**Version 12.2**

[image]

**Version 12.3.1**

[image]

Comment: If you use `PrintDefitions` and follow the `MakeBoxes` rule one level down you can find a flag to disable the new boxes

Comment: Yeah, that is a bug in 12.3.x.  You can report it if you like, but its not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I evaluate your `DSolve` command I mouse over the iconized `DifferentialRoot` object I see this
[image]

and when I click the icon I see this

[image]

which seems to me the easiest way to view the contents of the object. If you want a workaround for the `InputForm` bug I recommend [`shortInputForm`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/9490) - in fact I recommend it **always** instead of `InputForm`.

Finally if you want to avoid the iconization altogether you can define `` BoxForm`$NewHolonomicBoxes = False ``. The usual caveats of undocumented functionality apply, but it seems to disable the new boxes for this object.