# How can I exclude specific region in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, regions

I would like to exclude the region outside the yellow `Polygon` in this plot, how can I do that?

```
datr = Flatten[
   ParallelTable[{x, y, Sin[x y]}, {x, -3, 3, 0.1}, {y, -3, 3, 0.1}], 
   1];
plotTowD = 
  ListDensityPlot[datr, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Gray, Blue}, Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]] &),
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ClippingStyle -> Automatic];
Boundrs = {{-(\[Pi]/3), -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}, {-((2 \[Pi])/3), 
    0}, {-(\[Pi]/3), \[Pi]/Sqrt[3]}, {\[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/
     Sqrt[3]}, {(2 \[Pi])/3, 
    0}, {\[Pi]/3, -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}, {\[Pi]/
     3, -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}, {-(\[Pi]/3), -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}};
plot = ListLinePlot[Boundrs, PlotStyle -> Yellow];
Show[{plotTowD, plot}]
```

[image]

**update**

when adding `InterpolationOrder -> 0` to `ListDensityPlot` the answers provided below takes too long to give the output?!

Comment: use the option `RegionFunction -> (RegionMember[Polygon@Boundrs][{#, #2}] &)` in `ListDensityPlot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that is great, but why does it take too long time (84 sec) when adding `InterpolationOrder -> 0` to `ListDensityPlot`?

As I already demonstrated in the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261804/280) to another question of yours, using precomputed `RegionMemberFunction` as the value for the `RegionFunction` option gives huge speedup. In this particular case with `InterpolationOrder -> 0`:

```
Boundrs = {{-(π/3), -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {-((2 π)/3), 
    0}, {-(π/3), π/Sqrt[3]}, {π/3, π/
     Sqrt[3]}, {(2 π)/3, 
    0}, {π/3, -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {π/
     3, -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {-(π/3), -(π/Sqrt[3])}};
region = Polygon[Boundrs];
rf = RegionMember[region];
datr = Flatten[ParallelTable[{x, y, Sin[x y]}, {x, -3, 3, 0.1}, {y, -3, 3, 0.1}], 1];
plotTowD0 = ListDensityPlot[datr, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Gray, Blue}, Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]] &), 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, rf[{x, y}]], InterpolationOrder -> 0] // EchoTiming
```

> [image: output]

As to why computing with `InterpolationOrder -> 0` takes more time than with the default `InterpolationOrder -> 1`, let us compare the complexity of the obtained graphics (`plotTowD` is the same as `plotTowD0`, but is evaluated without the option `InterpolationOrder`):

```
Through[{LeafCount, ByteCount}[plotTowD]]
Through[{LeafCount, ByteCount}[plotTowD0]]
```

> ```
> {28976, 177384}
> ```

> ```
> {83650, 492160}
> ```

We see that the difference in complexity of obtained expressions is substantial! Let us check what is inside, using my [`shortInputForm`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280) function:

```
Import["http://raw.github.com/AlexeyPopkov/shortInputForm/master/shortInputForm.m"]

plotTowD // First // shortInputForm
plotTowD0 // First // shortInputForm
```

[image: screenshot]

We immediately see from the values of the option `VertexColors` that `plotTowD` contains 2204 colored vertex points between which the interiors of the `Polygon` objects are interpolated, while `plotTowD0` contains 8589 such points.
We also see that in the case of `plotTowD0` the obtained graphics is composed of 5663 `Polygon` objects, while `plotTowD` contains only 2566 of them! Apparently, with the option `InterpolationOrder -> 0` `ListDensityPlot` does a lot more work even though the resulting image looks simpler/rougher!

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: @valarmorghulis You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

```
Boundrs = {{-(π/3), -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {-((2 π)/3), 
    0}, {-(π/3), π/Sqrt[3]}, {π/3, π/
     Sqrt[3]}, {(2 π)/3, 
    0}, {π/3, -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {π/
     3, -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {-(π/3), -(π/Sqrt[3])}};
region = Polygon[Boundrs]
datr = Flatten[
   ParallelTable[{x, y, Sin[x y]}, {x, -3, 3, 0.1}, {y, -3, 3, 0.1}], 
   1];
plotTowD = 
 ListDensityPlot[datr, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Gray, Blue}, Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, {x, y} ∈ region]]
```

[image]

Comment: that is great, but why does it take too long time  (84 sec) when adding `InterpolationOrder -> 0` to `ListDensityPlot`?