# ListDensityPlot with RegionFunction takes too long?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, regions

I am using `ListDensityPlot` with `RegionFunction` (MMA12.3 on Win 64) but it takes too long

```
region = Polygon[{{-(\[Pi]/3), -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}, {-((2 \[Pi])/3), 
     0}, {-(\[Pi]/3), \[Pi]/Sqrt[3]}, {\[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/
      Sqrt[3]}, {(2 \[Pi])/3, 
     0}, {\[Pi]/3, -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}, {\[Pi]/
      3, -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}, {-(\[Pi]/3), -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}}];
datr = Flatten[
   ParallelTable[{x, y, Cos[x] Sin[x y]}, {x, -2.5, 2.5, 
     0.05}, {y, -2.5, 2.5, 0.05}], 1];
```

here is the result without `RegionFunction`

```
ListDensityPlot[datr, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Orange, Gray, Black}, 
      Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]] &), InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ClippingStyle -> Automatic] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

and with

```
ListDensityPlot[datr, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Orange, Gray, Black}, 
      Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]] &), InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y}, {x, y} \[Element] region]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont know why it takes so long. But I have a solution for you. Its sort of a hack

```
AbsoluteTiming[Show[ListDensityPlot[datr, ColorFunction -> 
          (Blend[{Orange, Gray, Black}, Rescale[#1, {-1, 1}]] & ), 
   InterpolationOrder -> 0, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
         ClippingStyle -> Automatic], 
    Graphics[{White, Polygon[{{-2.5, -2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}, {2.5,2.5}, {2.5, -2.5}} -> 
    {{-(Pi/3), -(Pi/Sqrt[3])}, {-((2*Pi)/3), 0}, {-(Pi/3), 
    Pi/Sqrt[3]}, {Pi/3, Pi/Sqrt[3]}, {(2*Pi)/3, 0}, 
    {Pi/3, -(Pi/Sqrt[3])}, {Pi/3, -(Pi/Sqrt[3])}, {-(Pi/3), -(Pi/Sqrt[3])}}]}]]]
```

[image]

This code takes far less time.On my machine it takes 2.11343 seconds.

I basically make a rectangular polygon with a hole in it.This hole is the polygon specified in your `region` variable.Then I use `Show` command to overlay the image and the polygon with the hole.

Check out the documentation for Polygon:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use pre-computed `RegionMemberFunction`:

```
Module[{rf = RegionMember[region]},
  ListDensityPlot[datr, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Orange, Gray, Black}, Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]] &), 
   InterpolationOrder -> 0, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, 
   RegionFunction -> (rf[{#1, #2}] &)]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> [image: output]