# Problems with PlotStyle in mathematica 10

Tags: bugs, plotting, compatibility

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

The simplest way to ask is to post the code of what I'm doing:

```
ListPlot[{Table[x, {x, 1, 10, 1}], Table[x + x^2, {x, 1, 10, 1}]}, 
  PlotMarkers -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {
   {Thickness[.005], Dashing[{.03, .015}], ColorData[1, 1]},   
   {Thickness[.0075], ColorData[1, 1]}},
  Joined -> True
]
```

When I did this in *Mathematica* 8, the first line was dashed and the second line was a thicker, solid line of the same color:

[image]

Now having upgraded to *Mathematica* 10 and the second line is also dashed, same as the first:

[image]

It seems that if I leave out an explicit `Dashing[{x,x}]` command, the curve inherits the last dashing style, rather than go back to the default!  How do I get the second curve to be solid?  More importantly, what has changed in *Mathematica* 10 that causes this?

Obviously, my real task is more complicated than this, but this will reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I confirm this problem (version 10 Wolfram Programming Cloud). Unless you explicitly use `Dashing[{}]` for a line, it inherits the `Dashing` spec from previous lines. It seems to happen only for the `Dashing` directive; other directives (Thickness, Color ...) seem to work fine. Btw, this happens with `ListPlot` (with the option `Joined->True`), not with `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: This is a bug, not a typo.

Comment: @rcollyer I wish you had tried harder to get my attention.  Question reopened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is missing a bracket and it should be a `ListLinePlot`. After correcting those errors I get one solid and one thinner dashed line just like you wanted.

```
ListLinePlot[{Table[x, {x, 1, 10, 1}], Table[x + x^2, {x, 1, 10, 1}]},
  PlotMarkers -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[.005], Dashing[{.03, .015}], 
    ColorData[1, 1]}, {Thickness[.0075], ColorData[1, 1]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thx Paw, this works for me.  The missing bracket was just a typo. Any clue as to what is going on differently under the hood of v10 vs v8?  I've run into a few issues like this where v10 seems to interpret my plotting commands differently v8.  It's usually not a big deal, but this particular plot I needed the style to match previously published work.

Comment: Question edited to fix the typo.  Should be correct now.  Can anyone point me in the right direection as to what is going on v/v the difference between v8 and v10 that causes this?

Comment: @Steve I had fixed the typo, and improved the formatting. You got rid of my formatting. :P Also, there's a lot of changes under the hood. Looks like a bug slipped through.

Comment: @rcollyer Sorry, I'm new to this stackexchange thing!  I upvoted your comment though.

Answer (score 4):

***This is fixed in 10.0.1.***  The output from `ListPlot` now matches that from `ListLinePlot`.

---

You are supposed to use [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListLinePlot.html) for line charts since *Mathematica* 6, which as paw illustrated handles this correctly.

The behavior of `ListPlot` is due to the structure of the `Graphics` object that is produced:

```
g1 = ListPlot[{Table[Sin[i], {i, 25}], Table[Cos[i], {i, 25}]}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick, Dashed}, {Blue, Thin}}];

g1[[1]] /. (h : Hue | Line | Directive)[___] :> h[]
```

> ```
> {{}, {Hue[], Directive[], Line[], Hue[], Directive[], Line[]}, {}}
> ```

Observe that the body is a single list of the form **{color, directive, line, color, directive, line, ...}**.
This has the implication that any earlier directive which is not expressly overridden by a later one will affect not only the `Line` immediately following it but all the rest.  Colors do not appear to persist in this fashion only because *Mathematica* automatically provides these styles.

Now compare the output of `ListLinePlot`:

```
g2 = ListLinePlot[{Table[Sin[i], {i, 25}], Table[Cos[i], {i, 25}]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick, Dashed}, {Blue, Thin}}];

g2[[1]] /. (h : Hue | Line | Directive)[___] :> h[]
```

> ```
> {{}, {{{}, {}, {Hue[], Directive[], Line[]}, {Hue[], Directive[], Line[]}}}, {}}
> ```

Note the structure **{{color, directive, line}, {color, directive, line}, ...}**.  This has the effect of localizing the styling directives to a specific line; they will not persist across multiple lines.

I suppose either behavior could be intentional but I find the latter less surprising, and therefore better.

---

The version 10.0.0 behavior has been confirmed as a bug.

1. > [This is a bug, not a typo. –  rcollyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58808/problems-with-plotstyle-in-mathematica-10/59466?noredirect=1#comment168131_58808) (WRI employee)
2. > [I reported the behavior of Dashed in ListPlot to WRI tech support, and in their reply they agreed it was a bug. Should the question, therefore, be tagged with the bugs tag? –  m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58992/how-do-you-turn-off-the-dashed-graphics-directive?lq=1#comment169189_58996)

Comment: "The version 10.0.0 behavior has been confirmed as a bug." By whom ? Thanks for ignoring my answer.

Comment: @eldo Citations added.  I did not ignore your answer; rather I feel that it does not properly address the question.

Comment: OK - Sorry for the downvote. It was too temperamental :)

Comment: @eldo Perhaps I was at fault too.  I was fixating on "*More importantly, what has changed in Mathematica 10 that causes this?*" but the OP did *also* ask "*How do I get the second curve to be solid?*" which you answered. +1 on yours as well.

Comment: @eldo the bug, as Mr.W points out, is that the data are no longer isolated from one another, (cf. [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32717/52)). There's a partial isolation as each data set gets a default color, but allowing other directives to leak across data sets is just icky.

Answer (score 1):

As per `Documentation` `Dashing[{}]` "specifies that lines should be solid". Hence

```
ListPlot[{Table[x, {x, 1, 10, 1}], Table[x + x^2, {x, 1, 10, 1}]},
 PlotMarkers -> None,
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotStyle -> {
   {Dashing[{.03, .015}], Thickness[.005], ColorData[1, 1]},
   {Dashing[{}], Thickness[.0075], ColorData[1, 1]}},
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

You have the same "problem" with **V9**.

Where are the **bugs** ? I just tried to remove this tag, but it stays.

Comment: Just because something was in v9, too, does not mean it should be there.

Comment: @rcollyer Continue to regard it as a "bug". For me it's logical. Kind of sorry that we disagree. –  eldo just now   edit