# How do you turn off the Dashed graphics directive?

Tags: graphics, bugs

I'm looking at [Graphics Directives](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphicsDirectives.html) but can't figure out a way to turn off the `Dashed` graphics directive. For example, given

```
ListPlot[{Table[Sin[i], {i, 25}], Table[Cos[i], {i, 25}]}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick, Dashed}, {Blue, Thin}}]
```

[image]

how do I restore a solid blue line? `Thick` can be "disabled" with `Thin` but what's `Dashed`'s complement?

Comment: That's odd. I'm running 9.0.1.0 for Windows x64.

Comment: Looks like a bug, but what happens if you invert Sin and Cos and the corresponding list of directives?

Comment: @Peltio - If I switch the directive sets then the results are as expected—sequentially applied. (If you're saying it's one way to achieve my desired results, then I should clarify that this is only a simplified example.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can turn it off with `Dashing[None]`.

```
ListPlot[{Table[Sin[i], {i, 25}], Table[Cos[i], {i, 25}]}, 
  Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick, Dashed}, {Dashing[None], Blue, Thin}}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: @AndrewCheong "_Dashing[{}] specifies that lines should be solid._" from the docs of `Dashing`, and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dashing.html#150207859) is the example they give :)

Comment: @Öskå - I missed that in the documentation. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @AndrewCheong So did I.. :)

Comment: It is my experience that wherever a graphic directive takes `{ }` as an off switch, it will take `None` as well.

Answer (score 11):

You are supposed to use [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListLinePlot.html) for line charts since *Mathematica* 6, which as eldo illustrated handles this correctly.

The behavior of `ListPlot` is due to the structure of the `Graphics` object that is produced:

```
g1 = ListPlot[{Table[Sin[i], {i, 25}], Table[Cos[i], {i, 25}]}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick, Dashed}, {Blue, Thin}}];

g1[[1]] /. (h : Hue | Line | Directive)[___] :> h[]
```

> ```
> {{}, {Hue[], Directive[], Line[], Hue[], Directive[], Line[]}, {}}
> ```

Observe that the body is a single list of the form **{color, directive, line, color, directive, line, ...}**.
This has the implication that any earlier directive which is not expressly overridden by a later one will affect not only the `Line` immediately following it but all the rest.  Colors do not appear to persist in this fashion only because *Mathematica* automatically provides these styles.

Now compare the output of `ListLinePlot`:

```
g2 = ListLinePlot[{Table[Sin[i], {i, 25}], Table[Cos[i], {i, 25}]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick, Dashed}, {Blue, Thin}}];

g2[[1]] /. (h : Hue | Line | Directive)[___] :> h[]
```

> ```
> {{}, {{{}, {}, {Hue[], Directive[], Line[]}, {Hue[], Directive[], Line[]}}}, {}}
> ```

Note the structure **{{color, directive, line}, {color, directive, line}, ...}**.  This has the effect of localizing the styling directives to a specific line; they will not persist across multiple lines.

I suppose either behavior could be intentional but I find the latter less surprising, and therefore better.

Comment: I reported the behavior of `Dashed` in `ListPlot` to WRI tech support, and in their reply they agreed it was a bug. Should the question, therefore, be tagged with the bugs tag?

Comment: @m_goldberg Based on that I believe it should so I added the tag.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Somehow easier for me than Mr. Goldberg's excellent answer:

```
ListLinePlot[{Table[Sin[i], {i, 25}], Table[Cos[i], {i, 25}]},
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick, Dashed}, {Blue, Thin}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the comments on the question were deleted, but it appears that depending on the version of Mathematica (or perhaps not that, but some other state of the environment), omitting `Dashed` in subsequent sets of directives does _not_ seem to disable the directive. Hence my asking.

Comment: Oh, wait. I didn't see until @Mr.Wizard pointed out, that you're using `ListLinePlot` instead of `ListPlot`.

Comment: @Andrew You may have overlooked the difference between `ListPlot` and `ListLinePlot`.  I expound on this in my own answer below.  In my opinion eldo's answer is the correct solution, but m_goldberg's is the direct answer to the specific question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Mr.Wizard answer , I would suggest for this particular example is to switch the data and to put the dashed data at the end.

```
ListPlot[{Table[Cos[i], {i, 25}], Table[Sin[i], {i, 25}]}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thin}, {Red, Thick, Dashed}}]
```

[image]