# Problem with dashed lines in Plot, ListPlot and ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, bugs

<sub>(I'm new stackexchange so I hope i'm doing this correctly).</sub>

I'm struggling with dashed lines in `Plot`, `ListPlot` or `ListLinePlot` with *Mathematica 10.0.1* on *Linux (64bits)*.

This has been declared as a [bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58808/problems-with-plotstyle-in-mathematica-10) with `ListPlot` in *Mathematica* *v9* and *v10* but is said to be [fixed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59466/22991) in *Mathematica 10.0.1*.

Using the code from this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59466/22991):

```
g2 = ListLinePlot[{Table[Sin[i], {i, 25}], Table[Cos[i], {i, 25}]}, 
      PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick, Dashed}, {Blue, Thin}}];`
```

produced the following image:

[image]

although the blue line should not be dashed.

Plotting

```
Plot[{Sin[i], Cos[i]}, {i, 1, 25},  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick, Dashed}, {Blue, Thin}}]
```

also produces only dashed lines.

The structure of the object produced by ListPlot  seems to be correct.

```
g2[[1]] /. (h : Hue | Line | Directive)[___] :> h[]
```

> ```
> {{}, {{{}, {}, {Hue[], Directive[], Line[]}, {Hue[], Directive[], Line[]}}}, {}}`
> ```

Running the same lines in *Mathematica 10.0.1*. on my *Mac* doesn't have this problem.

Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: @Öskå Nope, but I keep forgetting it. In fact, it makes me feel very uncomfortable

Comment: Thank you all, i didn't see the question mine is a duplicate of. If I understand everything correctly, this means that the ListPlot[] bug is closed but the linux Graphics[] bug is still there.