# Plot all curves in a table with a single color

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, color

I want all of my solutions in a table to be the same color. My attempt:

```
sol = DSolveValue[y'[t] == -2/t*y[t] + 4 t, y[t], t];
tbl = Table[sol /. C[1] -> C, {C, -1, 1, 0.25}];
Plot[tbl, {t, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]
```

produces:

[image]

Is there a simple way to make all curves blue?

Comment: Related: [(58808)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58808/121)

Answer (score 9):

```
PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}
```

You have a set of nine separate graphs, and `PlotStyle` applies each element in its list to subsequent graphs.  Thus if you put `PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}`, *Mathematica* applies `Thick` to the first graph, `Blue` to the second graph, `Thick` to the third, `Blue` to the fourth, and so on.  But if you set `PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}`, there is only one (compound) element in the list, so *Mathematica* keeps applying it to *every* graph.

Comment: I learned a lot from this answer.

Answer (score 8):

```
Plot[tbl, {t, -2, 2}, PlotStyle-> Directive[Thick,Blue]] (* or Directive[{Thick,Blue}] *)
```

[image]

Comment: Aha! Interesting. There is obviously a difference in the way PlotStyle->{Thick,Blue} and PlotStyle->Directive[Thick,Blue] perform. David Stork gave a nice explanation above. What is it about the Directive command that does not force me to write PlotStyle->Directive[{Thick,Blue}]?

Comment: @David, the docs ([Directive >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Directive.html)) says: `Directive[{Subscript[g, 1],Subscript[g, 2],\[Ellipsis]}] is equivalent to Directive[Subscript[g, 1],Subscript[g, 2],\[Ellipsis]].`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a very simple way.

```
Plot[tbl, {t, -2, 2}, ColorFunction -> (Blue &)]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: A very helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

```
 sol = DSolve[y'[t] == -2/t*y[t] + 4 t, y[t], t];
 resTable = 
    Flatten[y[t] /. Table[sol /. {C[1] -> C}, {C, -1, 1, 0.25}]];

 Show[
  Plot[#, {t, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}] & /@ resTable, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-5, 10}}]
```

> [image]

#### Update

```
Plot[#, {t, -2, 2}] & /@ resTable
```

> [image]

From this graphic, I can know the range of y axis is appoximately $[-30,20]$

```
Show[
  Plot[#, {t, -2, 2}] & /@ resTable, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-30, 20}}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Note how not all solutions make it up to 10 units even though PlotRange specifies the y-range to be [-5,10]. How come?

Comment: @David, See update:)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `Directive` but here's another alternative :)

```
Plot[# &@tbl, {t, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]
```

inspirated by the answer of Mr.Wizard (working till V9):

[Plot draws list of curves in same color when not using Evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1735/5478)

Comment: +1 for the mention, and that answer is now amended.