# Changing from Dashed to Solid

Tags: plotting, graphics, syntax

I have:

```
Graphics[{
  Blue, Thick,
  Arrow[{{0, 0}, f1}],
  Arrow[{{0, 0}, f2}],
  Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, f1 + f2}],
  Dashed, Blue,
  Line[{{-9, 0}, {12, 0}}]
  }]
```

Which produces this image.

[image]

Now, I want to continue, adding another line to my code, after the last line. I want to change from Dashed to solid again. How do I do that?

**Result due to helpful suggestions:**

```
f1 = 10 {Cos[135 °], Sin[135 °]};
f2 = 12 {Cos[30 °], Sin[30 °]};
```

Followed by:

```
Graphics[{
  Blue, Thick,
  Arrow[{{0, 0}, f1}],
  Arrow[{{0, 0}, f2}],
  Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, f1 + f2}],
  Dashed, Blue,
  Line[{{-9, 0}, {12, 0}}],
  Thickness[0.005], Arrowheads[Medium],
  Dashing[None], 
  Arrow[Table[5 {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, π/6, π/100}]],
  Arrow[Table[3 {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 3 π/4, π/100}]],
  Red, Arrow[Table[4 {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 1.3, π/100}]],
  Text[Style["F1", Blue], f1, {0, -1}],
  Text[Style["F2", Blue], f2, {0, -1}],
  Text[Style["F1+F2", Red], f1 + f2, {0, -1}],
  Text[Style["30°", Blue], 
   5.5 {Cos[13 °], Sin[13 °]}, {-1, 0}],
  Text[Style["135°", Blue], 
   3.5 {Cos[100 °], Sin[100 °]}, {0, -1}],
  Text[Style["θ", Red], 
   4.5 {Cos[50 °], Sin[50 °]}, {0, -1}],
  }]
```

Which produces the following image.

[image]

So folks were very helpful.

Comment: Within `Graphics[]`, you can use lists to localize the effect of a directive on a primitive. So, `Graphics[{Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}]` will render both lines blue, but `Graphics[{{Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}]` will only have the horizontal line be blue.

Comment: Strongly related: [(a/32717)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32717/280).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are two ways.

Using `Dashing[None]` to turn off dashing.

```
Graphics[{
   Dashed, Blue, Line[{{-9, 0}, {12, 0}}], 
   Dashing[None], Line[{{-9, -4}, {12, 4}}]}]
```

Using sub-lists to control the scope of directives.

```
Graphics[{
  Blue, 
   {Dashed, Line[{{-9, 0}, {12, 0}}]},
   Line[{{-9, -4}, {12, 4}}]}]
```

Both produce

[image: lines]

Comment: Also `Dashing[{}] specifies that lines should be solid` (from the docs)

Comment: Thank you. Am I the only one to be surprised that there's no `Solid` directive? Seems more logical than `Dashing[None]`...