# Setting graphics options back to default

Tags: graphics

How to set graphics options back to default? For example:

```
Graphics[{Dashed, Thick, Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}}], 
  Arrow[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}]}, Axes -> True]
```

I want the second arrow to not be dashed, thick and red, but "default". So I would not like to be explicit about what their values should be, but rather set something like Not-Dashed, Not-Thick, Not-Red.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Wrap everything up to the second arrow with `{}`.

Comment: Linked topic should answer your question but let me know if you disagree.

Comment: @Kuba I would close this as a dupe of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32712/280) question which has excellent general-purpose [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32717/280).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thanks, added to duplicates. Haven't seen it, well written indeed.